# Somewhere On The Tube ...But On Which Lines?

Tags: code-golf, graph-theory, compression

The [London Underground A.K.A. The Tube](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_Underground) is the oldest underground railway in the world, it currently consists of eleven lines* servicing 267 named stations (strictly 269** stations since "Edgware Road" and "Hammersmith" each occupy two locations)

#### The challenge

Output the names of the lines servicing a station given by name as input.

**Input:**
A string or list of characters

- This may be assumed to be a *valid* station name (as listed in the code-block below).
- You may assume any `&` in the input will *consistently* be the word `and` (or `And`) instead if you wish, just state it clearly in your answer.

**Output:**
*Separated* output listing those of the eleven lines servicing that station:

- A list of strings, a list of lists of characters, printed text, a string, a list of characters; if in doubt ask.
- You may *consistently* output the word `and` (or `And`) in place of any `&` if you wish, just state this clearly in your answer.
- With the caveat that if printing or returning a string or list of characters that the separator-substring used is not present in any of the line names (including the `&` or `and` or `And` used) - this therefore excludes the use of a single space character as the separator.

**The Tube Network**:
<sup>- Note: This is the final state, even if it happens to contain a spelling mistake (unless addressed prior to any answers)</sup>

```
Input (Station Name)         : Output (list of tube line names)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"Acton Town"                 : ["District","Piccadilly"]
"Aldgate"                    : ["Circle","Metropolitan"]
"Aldgate East"               : ["District","Hammersmith & City"]
"Alperton"                   : ["Piccadilly"]
"Amersham"                   : ["Metropolitan"]
"Angel"                      : ["Northern"]
"Archway"                    : ["Northern"]
"Arnos Grove"                : ["Piccadilly"]
"Arsenal"                    : ["Piccadilly"]
"Baker Street"               : ["Bakerloo","Circle","Hammersmith & City","Jubilee","Metropolitan"]
"Balham"                     : ["Northern"]
"Bank"                       : ["Central","Northern","Waterloo & City"]
"Barbican"                   : ["Circle","Hammersmith & City","Metropolitan"]
"Barking"                    : ["District","Hammersmith & City"]
"Barkingside"                : ["Central"]
"Barons Court"               : ["District","Piccadilly"]
"Bayswater"                  : ["Circle","District"]
"Becontree"                  : ["District"]
"Belsize Park"               : ["Northern"]
"Bermondsey"                 : ["Jubilee"]
"Bethnal Green"              : ["Central"]
"Blackfriars"                : ["Circle","District"]
"Blackhorse Road"            : ["Victoria"]
"Bond Street"                : ["Central","Jubilee"]
"Borough"                    : ["Northern"]
"Boston Manor"               : ["Piccadilly"]
"Bounds Green"               : ["Piccadilly"]
"Bow Road"                   : ["District","Hammersmith & City"]
"Brent Cross"                : ["Northern"]
"Brixton"                    : ["Victoria"]
"Bromley-by-Bow"             : ["District","Hammersmith & City"]
"Buckhurst Hill"             : ["Central"]
"Burnt Oak"                  : ["Northern"]
"Caledonian Road"            : ["Piccadilly"]
"Camden Town"                : ["Northern"]
"Canada Water"               : ["Jubilee"]
"Canary Wharf"               : ["Jubilee"]
"Canning Town"               : ["Jubilee"]
"Cannon Street"              : ["Circle","District"]
"Canons Park"                : ["Jubilee"]
"Chalfont & Latimer"         : ["Metropolitan"]
"Chalk Farm"                 : ["Northern"]
"Chancery Lane"              : ["Central"]
"Charing Cross"              : ["Bakerloo","Northern"]
"Chesham"                    : ["Metropolitan"]
"Chigwell"                   : ["Central"]
"Chiswick Park"              : ["District"]
"Chorleywood"                : ["Metropolitan"]
"Clapham Common"             : ["Northern"]
"Clapham North"              : ["Northern"]
"Clapham South"              : ["Northern"]
"Cockfosters"                : ["Piccadilly"]
"Colindale"                  : ["Northern"]
"Colliers Wood"              : ["Northern"]
"Covent Garden"              : ["Piccadilly"]
"Croxley"                    : ["Metropolitan"]
"Dagenham East"              : ["District"]
"Dagenham Heathway"          : ["District"]
"Debden"                     : ["Central"]
"Dollis Hill"                : ["Jubilee"]
"Ealing Broadway"            : ["Central","District"]
"Ealing Common"              : ["District","Piccadilly"]
"Earl's Court"               : ["District","Piccadilly"]
"East Acton"                 : ["Central"]
"East Finchley"              : ["Northern"]
"East Ham"                   : ["District","Hammersmith & City"]
"East Putney"                : ["District"]
"Eastcote"                   : ["Metropolitan","Piccadilly"]
"Edgware"                    : ["Northern"]
"Edgware Road"               : ["Bakerloo","Circle","District","Hammersmith & City"]
"Elephant & Castle"          : ["Bakerloo","Northern"]
"Elm Park"                   : ["District"]
"Embankment"                 : ["Bakerloo","Circle","District","Northern"]
"Epping"                     : ["Central"]
"Euston"                     : ["Northern","Victoria"]
"Euston Square"              : ["Circle","Hammersmith & City","Metropolitan"]
"Fairlop"                    : ["Central"]
"Farringdon"                 : ["Circle","Hammersmith & City","Metropolitan"]
"Finchley Central"           : ["Northern"]
"Finchley Road"              : ["Jubilee","Metropolitan"]
"Finsbury Park"              : ["Piccadilly","Victoria"]
"Fulham Broadway"            : ["District"]
"Gants Hill"                 : ["Central"]
"Gloucester Road"            : ["Circle","District","Piccadilly"]
"Golders Green"              : ["Northern"]
"Goldhawk Road"              : ["Circle","Hammersmith & City"]
"Goodge Street"              : ["Northern"]
"Grange Hill"                : ["Central"]
"Great Portland Street"      : ["Circle","Hammersmith & City","Metropolitan"]
"Greenford"                  : ["Central"]
"Green Park"                 : ["Jubilee","Piccadilly","Victoria"]
"Gunnersbury"                : ["District"]
"Hainault"                   : ["Central"]
"Hammersmith"                : ["Circle","District","Hammersmith & City","Piccadilly"]
"Hampstead"                  : ["Northern"]
"Hanger Lane"                : ["Central"]
"Harlesden"                  : ["Bakerloo"]
"Harrow & Wealdstone"        : ["Bakerloo"]
"Harrow-on-the-Hill"         : ["Metropolitan"]
"Hatton Cross"               : ["Piccadilly"]
"Heathrow Terminals 1, 2, 3" : ["Piccadilly"]
"Heathrow Terminal 4"        : ["Piccadilly"]
"Heathrow Terminal 5"        : ["Piccadilly"]
"Hendon Central"             : ["Northern"]
"High Barnet"                : ["Northern"]
"Highbury & Islington"       : ["Victoria"]
"Highgate"                   : ["Northern"]
"High Street Kensington"     : ["Circle","District"]
"Hillingdon"                 : ["Metropolitan","Piccadilly"]
"Holborn"                    : ["Central","Piccadilly"]
"Holland Park"               : ["Central"]
"Holloway Road"              : ["Piccadilly"]
"Hornchurch"                 : ["District"]
"Hounslow Central"           : ["Piccadilly"]
"Hounslow East"              : ["Piccadilly"]
"Hounslow West"              : ["Piccadilly"]
"Hyde Park Corner"           : ["Piccadilly"]
"Ickenham"                   : ["Metropolitan","Piccadilly"]
"Kennington"                 : ["Northern"]
"Kensal Green"               : ["Bakerloo"]
"Kensington (Olympia)"       : ["District"]
"Kentish Town"               : ["Northern"]
"Kenton"                     : ["Bakerloo"]
"Kew Gardens"                : ["District"]
"Kilburn"                    : ["Jubilee"]
"Kilburn Park"               : ["Bakerloo"]
"Kingsbury"                  : ["Jubilee"]
"King's Cross St. Pancras"   : ["Circle","Hammersmith & City","Metropolitan","Northern","Piccadilly","Victoria"]
"Knightsbridge"              : ["Piccadilly"]
"Ladbroke Grove"             : ["Circle","Hammersmith & City"]
"Lambeth North"              : ["Bakerloo"]
"Lancaster Gate"             : ["Central"]
"Latimer Road"               : ["Circle","Hammersmith & City"]
"Leicester Square"           : ["Northern","Piccadilly"]
"Leyton"                     : ["Central"]
"Leytonstone"                : ["Central"]
"Liverpool Street"           : ["Central","Circle","Hammersmith & City","Metropolitan"]
"London Bridge"              : ["Jubilee","Northern"]
"Loughton"                   : ["Central"]
"Maida Vale"                 : ["Bakerloo"]
"Manor House"                : ["Piccadilly"]
"Mansion House"              : ["Circle","District"]
"Marble Arch"                : ["Central"]
"Marylebone"                 : ["Bakerloo"]
"Mile End"                   : ["Central","District","Hammersmith & City"]
"Mill Hill East"             : ["Northern"]
"Monument"                   : ["Circle","District"]
"Moorgate"                   : ["Circle","Hammersmith & City","Metropolitan","Northern"]
"Moor Park"                  : ["Metropolitan"]
"Morden"                     : ["Northern"]
"Mornington Crescent"        : ["Northern"]
"Neasden"                    : ["Jubilee"]
"Newbury Park"               : ["Central"]
"North Acton"                : ["Central"]
"North Ealing"               : ["Piccadilly"]
"North Greenwich"            : ["Jubilee"]
"North Harrow"               : ["Metropolitan"]
"North Wembley"              : ["Bakerloo"]
"Northfields"                : ["Piccadilly"]
"Northolt"                   : ["Central"]
"Northwick Park"             : ["Metropolitan"]
"Northwood"                  : ["Metropolitan"]
"Northwood Hills"            : ["Metropolitan"]
"Notting Hill Gate"          : ["Central","Circle","District"]
"Oakwood"                    : ["Piccadilly"]
"Old Street"                 : ["Northern"]
"Osterley"                   : ["Piccadilly"]
"Oval"                       : ["Northern"]
"Oxford Circus"              : ["Bakerloo","Central","Victoria"]
"Paddington"                 : ["Bakerloo","Circle","District","Hammersmith & City"]
"Park Royal"                 : ["Piccadilly"]
"Parsons Green"              : ["District"]
"Perivale"                   : ["Central"]
"Piccadilly Circus"          : ["Bakerloo","Piccadilly"]
"Pimlico"                    : ["Victoria"]
"Pinner"                     : ["Metropolitan"]
"Plaistow"                   : ["District","Hammersmith & City"]
"Preston Road"               : ["Metropolitan"]
"Putney Bridge"              : ["District"]
"Queen's Park"               : ["Bakerloo"]
"Queensbury"                 : ["Jubilee"]
"Queensway"                  : ["Central"]
"Ravenscourt Park"           : ["District"]
"Rayners Lane"               : ["Metropolitan","Piccadilly"]
"Redbridge"                  : ["Central"]
"Regent's Park"              : ["Bakerloo"]
"Richmond"                   : ["District"]
"Rickmansworth"              : ["Metropolitan"]
"Roding Valley"              : ["Central"]
"Royal Oak"                  : ["Circle","Hammersmith & City"]
"Ruislip"                    : ["Metropolitan","Piccadilly"]
"Ruislip Gardens"            : ["Central"]
"Ruislip Manor"              : ["Metropolitan","Piccadilly"]
"Russell Square"             : ["Piccadilly"]
"St. James's Park"           : ["Circle","District"]
"St. John's Wood"            : ["Jubilee"]
"St. Paul's"                 : ["Central"]
"Seven Sisters"              : ["Victoria"]
"Shepherd's Bush"            : ["Central"]
"Shepherd's Bush Market"     : ["Circle","Hammersmith & City"]
"Sloane Square"              : ["Circle","District"]
"Snaresbrook"                : ["Central"]
"South Ealing"               : ["Piccadilly"]
"South Harrow"               : ["Piccadilly"]
"South Kensington"           : ["Circle","District","Piccadilly"]
"South Kenton"               : ["Bakerloo"]
"South Ruislip"              : ["Central"]
"South Wimbledon"            : ["Northern"]
"South Woodford"             : ["Central"]
"Southfields"                : ["District"]
"Southgate"                  : ["Piccadilly"]
"Southwark"                  : ["Jubilee"]
"Stamford Brook"             : ["District"]
"Stanmore"                   : ["Jubilee"]
"Stepney Green"              : ["District","Hammersmith & City"]
"Stockwell"                  : ["Northern","Victoria"]
"Stonebridge Park"           : ["Bakerloo"]
"Stratford"                  : ["Central","Jubilee"]
"Sudbury Hill"               : ["Piccadilly"]
"Sudbury Town"               : ["Piccadilly"]
"Swiss Cottage"              : ["Jubilee"]
"Temple"                     : ["Circle","District"]
"Theydon Bois"               : ["Central"]
"Tooting Bec"                : ["Northern"]
"Tooting Broadway"           : ["Northern"]
"Tottenham Court Road"       : ["Central","Northern"]
"Tottenham Hale"             : ["Victoria"]
"Totteridge & Whetstone"     : ["Northern"]
"Tower Hill"                 : ["Circle","District"]
"Tufnell Park"               : ["Northern"]
"Turnham Green"              : ["District","Piccadilly"]
"Turnpike Lane"              : ["Piccadilly"]
"Upminster"                  : ["District"]
"Upminster Bridge"           : ["District"]
"Upney"                      : ["District"]
"Upton Park"                 : ["District","Hammersmith & City"]
"Uxbridge"                   : ["Metropolitan","Piccadilly"]
"Vauxhall"                   : ["Victoria"]
"Victoria"                   : ["Circle","District","Victoria"]
"Walthamstow Central"        : ["Victoria"]
"Wanstead"                   : ["Central"]
"Warren Street"              : ["Northern","Victoria"]
"Warwick Avenue"             : ["Bakerloo"]
"Waterloo"                   : ["Bakerloo","Jubilee","Northern","Waterloo & City"]
"Watford"                    : ["Metropolitan"]
"Wembley Central"            : ["Bakerloo"]
"Wembley Park"               : ["Jubilee","Metropolitan"]
"West Acton"                 : ["Central"]
"West Brompton"              : ["District"]
"West Finchley"              : ["Northern"]
"West Ham"                   : ["District","Hammersmith & City","Jubilee"]
"West Hampstead"             : ["Jubilee"]
"West Harrow"                : ["Metropolitan"]
"West Kensington"            : ["District"]
"West Ruislip"               : ["Central"]
"Westbourne Park"            : ["Circle","Hammersmith & City"]
"Westminster"                : ["Circle","District","Jubilee"]
"White City"                 : ["Central"]
"Whitechapel"                : ["District","Hammersmith & City"]
"Willesden Green"            : ["Jubilee"]
"Willesden Junction"         : ["Bakerloo"]
"Wimbledon"                  : ["District"]
"Wimbledon Park"             : ["District"]
"Wood Green"                 : ["Piccadilly"]
"Wood Lane"                  : ["Circle","Hammersmith & City"]
"Woodford"                   : ["Central"]
"Woodside Park"              : ["Northern"]
```

...the eleven line names are:

```
Bakerloo
Central
Circle
District
Hammersmith & City
Jubilee
Metropolitan
Northern
Piccadilly
Victoria
Waterloo & City
```

* Transport For London do manage other train lines too, some may also be referred to as being part of "The Tube" (most likely the "Docklands Light Railway" or "DLR") but we shall stick to the eleven listed here.

** The linked Wikipedia page currently states 270, but I believe they are mistakenly counting the second location of Canary Wharf even though it only services the "DLR")

---

Heaps of imaginary brownie points (and most likely many upvotes too) for a golfed submission using [Mornington Crescent](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Mornington_Crescent) (a compatible IDE is available [here](https://github.com/Timwi/EsotericIDE/))!

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins per language and the shortest solution wins (don't let golfing languages put you off golfing in other languages). Have fun!

Comment: I'm just gonna leave [this](https://pastebin.com/SAx07Xb6) here. I don't even wanna submit this answer. >_> I didn't... realize how... big this is...

Comment: @icrieverytim Get your golfing gloves on :)

Comment: So it's just ... [a series of tubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_of_tubes), right? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Arnauld Absolutely, indeed, not at all, yes. You can "get on a tube", you can "change tubes", you can "be on the wrong tube", you can "get the first tube" or "get the last tube" ...but there is only one Tube :)

Comment: Now [sing them](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jPyg2pK11M) with Jay Foreman.

Comment: An alternative explanation for the 269/270 discrepancy in your sub-footnote is Paddington, where the Hammersmith and City station at the level of the mainline platforms is distinct from the low level Bakerloo and District/Circle lines.

Comment: Does the version of `and` used for input have to be the same as the version used for output? Or is it fine if all inputs use one version and all outputs use another?

Comment: @KamilDrakari It's fine to use different ones for input and output so long as they are consistent.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Mathematica 8+, 266 bytes

```
t=Merge[Cases[<<ExamplePages/TripPlanning.nb,_@v__~_~{_->l_}:>(#->l&/@{v}),-1],Union@@#&];
x(r=t@@Nearest[Keys@t]@StringReplace[__~~"d Lane"|"ket"->"Royal Oak"]@x;DeleteCases[
  If[x<>r[[1]]//StringFreeQ@"sm",{},{"Circle"}]⋃r,"Overground"|"Docklands Light Rail"])
```

This solution originally had the same number of bytes as there are stations. I suppose it could be golfed down another 50 or so bytes, but this seemed like a fitting place to stop for now.

---

### Introduction

Mathematica is well known for its large standard library and access to a large online "computable knowledge base." I brazenly searched Wolfram|Alpha hoping to easily find the relevant transit data, but [although it understands the domain of my query, the data is not yet available](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Piccadilly+Line).

Fortunately, Mathematica's extensive built-in documentation comes with neat examples. [Several of those pages](http://reference.wolfram.com/search/?q=London%20Underground) just happen to use the London Underground network to demonstrate graph-related functionality. We will use the graph from the ["Trip Planning" featured example](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/TripPlanning.html) due to its short name.

> [image]

<sup>[Here are other cool uses of the same network](https://visualign.wordpress.com/2012/07/11/london-tube-map-and-graph-visualizations/).</sup>

I do not believe that programmatically accessing Mathematica's own documentation falls into the ["Fetching from an external source"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1062/20007)-type loopholes.

---

### Import the example page

We can import the example page as a [notebook expression](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NotebooksAsWolframLanguageExpressions.html):

```
<<ExamplePages/TripPlanning.nb
```

> ```
> Notebook[{Cell[ ... ], ... }, Saveable -> False, ...]
> ```

It is possible to extract the whole graph from deep inside the notebook expression:

```
g = FirstCase[<< ExamplePages/TripPlanning.nb, _Graph, , -1];
VertexList[g]
```

> ```
> {"Acton Central", "Acton Town", "Aldgate", ...}
> ```

Note that the vertices of the graph are just the station names. The edges have a custom `"Lines"` property that is a list of strings representing the lines that pass between its two stations:

```
# -> PropertyValue[{g, #}, "Lines"] & /@ EdgeList[g]
```

> ```
> {...,
>  "Acton Town" <-> "Chiswick Park" -> {"District"}, 
>  "Acton Town" <-> "Ealing Common" -> {"District", "Piccadilly"},
>  ...}
> ```

Now, we could find all the lines passing through a vertex by getting all its incident edges from `IncidenceList[g, vertex]`, mapping `PropertyValue[{g, edge}, "Lines"]` over them, and so on.

However, we will skip the above method and save many bytes by pattern matching for the relevant part of the `Graph` constructor – the [`Properties`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html#598959375) option.

### Extract the lines

The `Graph` constructor has the following format:

```
Graph[
  {v1, v2, ...},
  {e1, e2, ...},
  Properties -> {
    v1 -> {propertyName -> propertyValue},
    e1 -> {propertyName -> propertyValue},   (* one edge property *)
    ...
  }
]
```

<sup>(You can see this by inspecting `FullForm[g]` or reading the source code of `TripPlanning.nb` – for its full path, run `FindFile["ExamplePages/TripPlanning.nb"]`.)</sup>

Here is an example of one edge property:

```
UndirectedEdge["Embankment", "Waterloo"] -> {"Lines" -> {"Bakerloo", "Northern"}}
```

Let's turn this expression into a compact pattern:

```
UndirectedEdge[v1_, v2_]  ->      {"Lines" -> lines_}
UndirectedEdge[v1_, v2_]  ~Rule~  {"Lines" -> lines_}
UndirectedEdge[v__]       ~Rule~  {_       -> lines_}
             _[v__]       ~Rule~  {_       -> l_    }
             _@v__        ~_~     {_       -> l_    }

             _@v__~_~{_->l_}
```

### Make a lookup table

Now we can match `v1`, `v2`, and `lines`, but we want `{v1 -> lines, v2 -> lines}`. Helpfully, [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) can simultaneously match a pattern and transform it.

```
Cases[notebook,  _@v__~_~{_->l_} :> (# -> l & /@ { v }),  -1]
                 [ the pattern ]    [ the replacement ]
```

This produces a list of the form `{{v1 -> lines, v2 -> lines}, {v1 -> lines, v3 -> lines}, ...}`. Finally, we merge the list by vertex:

```
t=Merge[Cases[...], Union@@#&];
```

In under 90 bytes, we have produced an almost-perfect lookup table for each station's lines.

```
t=Merge[Cases[<<ExamplePages/TripPlanning.nb,_@s__~_~{_->l_}:>(#->l&/@{s}),-1],Union@@#&]
```

> ```
> <| "Embankment"       -> {"Bakerloo", "Circle", "District", "Northern"},
>    "Waterloo"         -> {"Bakerloo", "Jubilee", "Northern", "Waterloo & City"},
>    "Brondesbury"      -> {"Overground"},
>     ... |>
> ```

---

### Fix typos

Unfortunately, some station names are misspelled or missing.

Fuzzy string matching should take care of the typos. We can find the [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest.html) misspelled station name to the input station name:

```
Nearest[Keys@t]
```

Replace inputs of `"Wood Lane"` and `"Shepherd's Bush Market"` (new stations) with `"Royal Oak"`, since those three stations share the same lines:

```
StringReplace[__ ~~ "d Lane" | "ket" -> "Royal Oak"]
```

Compose those functions to get the fake station name, look up its lines in the table, and store in `r`:

```
r=t@@Nearest[Keys@t]@StringReplace[__~~"d Lane"|"ket"->"Royal Oak"]@x
```

### Fix outdated

The network is also slightly outdated due to the Circle Line overhaul.

If the input station is `"Hammersmith"` or if the lookup table returns only `{"Hammersmith & City"}`, then add `"Circle"` to the lines.

```
If[x <> r[[1]] // StringFreeQ@"sm", {}, {"Circle"}] ⋃ r
```

### Remove extraneous lines

The graph contains some lines that we don't care about, so remove them:

```
DeleteCases[..., "Overground"|"Docklands Light Rail"]
```

That's it!

---

### Try it! (with workarounds)

If you want to play around with my solution but don't have Mathematica, you can use the free Wolfram Programming Cloud. [Go here](https://develop.open.wolframcloud.com/app/), click `Create a New Notebook`, then wait a moment.

Unfortunately, the platform has some limitations that prevent my notebook-importing code from working. Here are some crude workarounds:

Since the example page is not there, we can try to abuse the copy-input-to-clipboard function from the online documentation. I used my browser's developer tools and saw that a request was made to [`http://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/Files/TripPlanning.en/i_1.txt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/Files/TripPlanning.en/i_1.txt) (warning: large). However, the platform's proxy doesn't resolve the domain `reference.wolfram.com`, so I just did it manually.

```
gWorkaround = ToExpression[
  FirstCase[
    Import["http://140.177.205.163/language/example/Files/TripPlanning.en/i_1.txt",
      {"HTML","XMLObject"}],
    XMLElement["pre", _, {a_}] :> a,
    ,-1
  ],
  InputForm, Hold];
```

Paste this in first and press <kbd>shift+enter</kbd> to execute. Now replace `<<ExamplePages/TripPlanning.nb` with `gWorkaround`.

---

### Test data

Call the function `f` and test it on the given data:

```
f = %;

testData = <|"Acton Town" -> {"District", "Piccadilly"}, "Aldgate" -> {"Circle", "Metropolitan"}, "Aldgate East" -> {"District", "Hammersmith & City"}, "Alperton" -> {"Piccadilly"}, "Amersham" -> {"Metropolitan"}, "Angel" -> {"Northern"}, "Archway" -> {"Northern"}, "Arnos Grove" -> {"Piccadilly"}, "Arsenal" -> {"Piccadilly"}, "Baker Street" -> {"Bakerloo", "Circle", "Hammersmith & City", "Jubilee", "Metropolitan"}, "Balham" -> {"Northern"}, "Bank" -> {"Central", "Northern", "Waterloo & City"}, "Barbican" -> {"Circle", "Hammersmith & City", "Metropolitan"}, "Barking" -> {"District", "Hammersmith & City"}, "Barkingside" -> {"Central"}, "Barons Court" -> {"District", "Piccadilly"}, "Bayswater" -> {"Circle", "District"}, "Becontree" -> {"District"}, "Belsize Park" -> {"Northern"}, "Bermondsey" -> {"Jubilee"}, "Bethnal Green" -> {"Central"}, "Blackfriars" -> {"Circle", "District"}, "Blackhorse Road" -> {"Victoria"}, "Bond Street" -> {"Central", "Jubilee"}, "Borough" -> {"Northern"}, "Boston Manor" -> {"Piccadilly"}, "Bounds Green" -> {"Piccadilly"}, "Bow Road" -> {"District", "Hammersmith & City"}, "Brent Cross" -> {"Northern"}, "Brixton" -> {"Victoria"}, "Bromley-by-Bow" -> {"District", "Hammersmith & City"}, "Buckhurst Hill" -> {"Central"}, "Burnt Oak" -> {"Northern"}, "Caledonian Road" -> {"Piccadilly"}, "Camden Town" -> {"Northern"}, "Canada Water" -> {"Jubilee"}, "Canary Wharf" -> {"Jubilee"}, "Canning Town" -> {"Jubilee"}, "Cannon Street" -> {"Circle", "District"}, "Canons Park" -> {"Jubilee"}, "Chalfont & Latimer" -> {"Metropolitan"}, "Chalk Farm" -> {"Northern"}, "Chancery Lane" -> {"Central"}, "Charing Cross" -> {"Bakerloo", "Northern"}, "Chesham" -> {"Metropolitan"}, "Chigwell" -> {"Central"}, "Chiswick Park" -> {"District"}, "Chorleywood" -> {"Metropolitan"}, "Clapham Common" -> {"Northern"}, "Clapham North" -> {"Northern"}, "Clapham South" -> {"Northern"}, "Cockfosters" -> {"Piccadilly"}, "Colindale" -> {"Northern"}, "Colliers Wood" -> {"Northern"}, "Covent Garden" -> {"Piccadilly"}, "Croxley" -> {"Metropolitan"}, "Dagenham East" -> {"District"}, "Dagenham Heathway" -> {"District"}, "Debden" -> {"Central"}, "Dollis Hill" -> {"Jubilee"}, "Ealing Broadway" -> {"Central", "District"}, "Ealing Common" -> {"District", "Piccadilly"}, "Earl's Court" -> {"District", "Piccadilly"}, "East Acton" -> {"Central"}, "East Finchley" -> {"Northern"}, "East Ham" -> {"District", "Hammersmith & City"}, "East Putney" -> {"District"}, "Eastcote" -> {"Metropolitan", "Piccadilly"}, "Edgware" -> {"Northern"}, "Edgware Road" -> {"Bakerloo", "Circle", "District", "Hammersmith & City"}, "Elephant & Castle" -> {"Bakerloo", "Northern"}, "Elm Park" -> {"District"}, "Embankment" -> {"Bakerloo", "Circle", "District", "Northern"}, "Epping" -> {"Central"}, "Euston" -> {"Northern", "Victoria"}, "Euston Square" -> {"Circle", "Hammersmith & City", "Metropolitan"}, "Fairlop" -> {"Central"}, "Farringdon" -> {"Circle", "Hammersmith & City", "Metropolitan"}, "Finchley Central" -> {"Northern"}, "Finchley Road" -> {"Jubilee", "Metropolitan"}, "Finsbury Park" -> {"Piccadilly", "Victoria"}, "Fulham Broadway" -> {"District"}, "Gants Hill" -> {"Central"}, "Gloucester Road" -> {"Circle", "District", "Piccadilly"}, "Golders Green" -> {"Northern"}, "Goldhawk Road" -> {"Circle", "Hammersmith & City"}, "Goodge Street" -> {"Northern"}, "Grange Hill" -> {"Central"}, "Great Portland Street" -> {"Circle", "Hammersmith & City", "Metropolitan"}, "Greenford" -> {"Central"}, "Green Park" -> {"Jubilee", "Piccadilly", "Victoria"}, "Gunnersbury" -> {"District"}, "Hainault" -> {"Central"}, "Hammersmith" -> {"Circle", "District", "Hammersmith & City", "Piccadilly"}, "Hampstead" -> {"Northern"}, "Hanger Lane" -> {"Central"}, "Harlesden" -> {"Bakerloo"}, "Harrow & Wealdstone" -> {"Bakerloo"}, "Harrow-on-the-Hill" -> {"Metropolitan"}, "Hatton Cross" -> {"Piccadilly"}, "Heathrow Terminals 1, 2, 3" -> {"Piccadilly"}, "Heathrow Terminal 4" -> {"Piccadilly"}, "Heathrow Terminal 5" -> {"Piccadilly"}, "Hendon Central" -> {"Northern"}, "High Barnet" -> {"Northern"}, "Highbury & Islington" -> {"Victoria"}, "Highgate" -> {"Northern"}, "High Street Kensington" -> {"Circle", "District"}, "Hillingdon" -> {"Metropolitan", "Piccadilly"}, "Holborn" -> {"Central", "Piccadilly"}, "Holland Park" -> {"Central"}, "Holloway Road" -> {"Piccadilly"}, "Hornchurch" -> {"District"}, "Hounslow Central" -> {"Piccadilly"}, "Hounslow East" -> {"Piccadilly"}, "Hounslow West" -> {"Piccadilly"}, "Hyde Park Corner" -> {"Piccadilly"}, "Ickenham" -> {"Metropolitan", "Piccadilly"}, "Kennington" -> {"Northern"}, "Kensal Green" -> {"Bakerloo"}, "Kensington (Olympia)" -> {"District"}, "Kentish Town" -> {"Northern"}, "Kenton" -> {"Bakerloo"}, "Kew Gardens" -> {"District"}, "Kilburn" -> {"Jubilee"}, "Kilburn Park" -> {"Bakerloo"}, "Kingsbury" -> {"Jubilee"}, "King's Cross St. Pancras" -> {"Circle", "Hammersmith & City", "Metropolitan", "Northern", "Piccadilly", "Victoria"}, "Knightsbridge" -> {"Piccadilly"}, "Ladbroke Grove" -> {"Circle", "Hammersmith & City"}, "Lambeth North" -> {"Bakerloo"}, "Lancaster Gate" -> {"Central"}, "Latimer Road" -> {"Circle", "Hammersmith & City"}, "Leicester Square" -> {"Northern", "Piccadilly"}, "Leyton" -> {"Central"}, "Leytonstone" -> {"Central"}, "Liverpool Street" -> {"Central", "Circle", "Hammersmith & City", "Metropolitan"}, "London Bridge" -> {"Jubilee", "Northern"}, "Loughton" -> {"Central"}, "Maida Vale" -> {"Bakerloo"}, "Manor House" -> {"Piccadilly"}, "Mansion House" -> {"Circle", "District"}, "Marble Arch" -> {"Central"}, "Marylebone" -> {"Bakerloo"}, "Mile End" -> {"Central", "District", "Hammersmith & City"}, "Mill Hill East" -> {"Northern"}, "Monument" -> {"Circle", "District"}, "Moorgate" -> {"Circle", "Hammersmith & City", "Metropolitan", "Northern"}, "Moor Park" -> {"Metropolitan"}, "Morden" -> {"Northern"}, "Mornington Crescent" -> {"Northern"}, "Neasden" -> {"Jubilee"}, "Newbury Park" -> {"Central"}, "North Acton" -> {"Central"}, "North Ealing" -> {"Piccadilly"}, "North Greenwich" -> {"Jubilee"}, "North Harrow" -> {"Metropolitan"}, "North Wembley" -> {"Bakerloo"}, "Northfields" -> {"Piccadilly"}, "Northolt" -> {"Central"}, "Northwick Park" -> {"Metropolitan"}, "Northwood" -> {"Metropolitan"}, "Northwood Hills" -> {"Metropolitan"}, "Notting Hill Gate" -> {"Central", "Circle", "District"}, "Oakwood" -> {"Piccadilly"}, "Old Street" -> {"Northern"}, "Osterley" -> {"Piccadilly"}, "Oval" -> {"Northern"}, "Oxford Circus" -> {"Bakerloo", "Central", "Victoria"}, "Paddington" -> {"Bakerloo", "Circle", "District", "Hammersmith & City"}, "Park Royal" -> {"Piccadilly"}, "Parsons Green" -> {"District"}, "Perivale" -> {"Central"}, "Piccadilly Circus" -> {"Bakerloo", "Piccadilly"}, "Pimlico" -> {"Victoria"}, "Pinner" -> {"Metropolitan"}, "Plaistow" -> {"District", "Hammersmith & City"}, "Preston Road" -> {"Metropolitan"}, "Putney Bridge" -> {"District"}, "Queen's Park" -> {"Bakerloo"}, "Queensbury" -> {"Jubilee"}, "Queensway" -> {"Central"}, "Ravenscourt Park" -> {"District"}, "Rayners Lane" -> {"Metropolitan", "Piccadilly"}, "Redbridge" -> {"Central"}, "Regent's Park" -> {"Bakerloo"}, "Richmond" -> {"District"}, "Rickmansworth" -> {"Metropolitan"}, "Roding Valley" -> {"Central"}, "Royal Oak" -> {"Circle", "Hammersmith & City"}, "Ruislip" -> {"Metropolitan", "Piccadilly"}, "Ruislip Gardens" -> {"Central"}, "Ruislip Manor" -> {"Metropolitan", "Piccadilly"}, "Russell Square" -> {"Piccadilly"}, "St. James's Park" -> {"Circle", "District"}, "St. John's Wood" -> {"Jubilee"}, "St. Paul's" -> {"Central"}, "Seven Sisters" -> {"Victoria"}, "Shepherd's Bush" -> {"Central"}, "Shepherd's Bush Market" -> {"Circle", "Hammersmith & City"}, "Sloane Square" -> {"Circle", "District"}, "Snaresbrook" -> {"Central"}, "South Ealing" -> {"Piccadilly"}, "South Harrow" -> {"Piccadilly"}, "South Kensington" -> {"Circle", "District", "Piccadilly"}, "South Kenton" -> {"Bakerloo"}, "South Ruislip" -> {"Central"}, "South Wimbledon" -> {"Northern"}, "South Woodford" -> {"Central"}, "Southfields" -> {"District"}, "Southgate" -> {"Piccadilly"}, "Southwark" -> {"Jubilee"}, "Stamford Brook" -> {"District"}, "Stanmore" -> {"Jubilee"}, "Stepney Green" -> {"District", "Hammersmith & City"}, "Stockwell" -> {"Northern", "Victoria"}, "Stonebridge Park" -> {"Bakerloo"}, "Stratford" -> {"Central", "Jubilee"}, "Sudbury Hill" -> {"Piccadilly"}, "Sudbury Town" -> {"Piccadilly"}, "Swiss Cottage" -> {"Jubilee"}, "Temple" -> {"Circle", "District"}, "Theydon Bois" -> {"Central"}, "Tooting Bec" -> {"Northern"}, "Tooting Broadway" -> {"Northern"}, "Tottenham Court Road" -> {"Central", "Northern"}, "Tottenham Hale" -> {"Victoria"}, "Totteridge & Whetstone" -> {"Northern"}, "Tower Hill" -> {"Circle", "District"}, "Tufnell Park" -> {"Northern"}, "Turnham Green" -> {"District", "Piccadilly"}, "Turnpike Lane" -> {"Piccadilly"}, "Upminster" -> {"District"}, "Upminster Bridge" -> {"District"}, "Upney" -> {"District"}, "Upton Park" -> {"District", "Hammersmith & City"}, "Uxbridge" -> {"Metropolitan", "Piccadilly"}, "Vauxhall" -> {"Victoria"}, "Victoria" -> {"Circle", "District", "Victoria"}, "Walthamstow Central" -> {"Victoria"}, "Wanstead" -> {"Central"}, "Warren Street" -> {"Northern", "Victoria"}, "Warwick Avenue" -> {"Bakerloo"}, "Waterloo" -> {"Bakerloo", "Jubilee", "Northern", "Waterloo & City"}, "Watford" -> {"Metropolitan"}, "Wembley Central" -> {"Bakerloo"}, "Wembley Park" -> {"Jubilee", "Metropolitan"}, "West Acton" -> {"Central"}, "West Brompton" -> {"District"}, "West Finchley" -> {"Northern"}, "West Ham" -> {"District", "Hammersmith & City", "Jubilee"}, "West Hampstead" -> {"Jubilee"}, "West Harrow" -> {"Metropolitan"}, "West Kensington" -> {"District"}, "West Ruislip" -> {"Central"}, "Westbourne Park" -> {"Circle", "Hammersmith & City"}, "Westminster" -> {"Circle", "District", "Jubilee"}, "White City" -> {"Central"}, "Whitechapel" -> {"District", "Hammersmith & City"}, "Willesden Green" -> {"Jubilee"}, "Willesden Junction" -> {"Bakerloo"}, "Wimbledon" -> {"District"}, "Wimbledon Park" -> {"District"}, "Wood Green" -> {"Piccadilly"}, "Wood Lane" -> {"Circle", "Hammersmith & City"}, "Woodford" -> {"Central"}, "Woodside Park" -> {"Northern"}|>;

KeyValueMap[{#, f[#] == #2} &, testData] // Grid
```

Comment: Does the language actually ship with the required documentation? If not I'd suggest the title should be "Mathematica 8+ (with <documentation name>)", definitely borderline use-of-external-resource but I see a lot of effort went in (especially since the notebook is outdated).

Comment: Yes, Mathematica does actually ship with its documentation.

Comment: If the language ships with all this example file by default then I don't think any loophole has been used (I cannot verify this since Mathematica is not free, so if anyone else can I'd personally appreciate the confirmation). Great answer in any case by the way!

Answer (score 16):

## ES6, Node.js / Chrome, <s>989</s> <s>977</s> <s>931</s> <s>892</s> <s>889</s> 887 bytes

```js
s=>"Bakerloo,Central,Circle,District,Hammersmith & City,Jubilee,Metropolitan,Northern,Piccadilly,Victoria,Waterloo & City".split`,`.filter((_,i)=>parseInt('7c1w0o741s3k39w22c020c080we80y3l0a8w0t3xhs2olc7g0km87w0176r8ao2e4g0q5w0eeb753mekwx1k18'.substr(" 5Kd5_9 5c4^5];`3]3 4]4^<`Y`0^5h3 9 ;<K 9^2b<`3 Wf9 9`E 0<a;< ; 9`;]2o4b99a33d5`; 3`3jB]Kj9b55e8m5]= KmS ;]K5`9^9]<_3^0 ;]3_3]3 99;b=]K 3 Xe95`9_Qd5_0o3b;];bKf=e=b3jH_<]4d; 3g:d45eT]J_5Kk4{2q9_Kc4c<l9vD`9; 9eIc2^D]<]5a3d8`5hF 4jKhLUm3|5]: ;a5{<> :^3d5t9]5l6_A~f9h5]5b5b9hK]9]: 5l4:a5m9}4^@oHkH^3e3c1c4nBf<bHa:w=b;]AsDl; K`H~K]3d;f8r9 4n9eV]9 <^9~3n=l<]9]5]5a9kK 5 5`: =g:aHcAb2q?_2b0tAsNc;]9]9_3e5e3qAkR^Ac5bK Mc?a;9t=y2_;]5b3_2e<vOd4_9i;^C`9w;a3p:a<j9]5 7Ke:_<3 9`5_Ga4h9t8_9^>e3]H^Eg5zAe4cZ_;ePGm2 3a3".replace(/./g,c=>c.repeat((n=c[C='charCodeAt']())<92||n-91))[C](parseInt(s.replace(/\W|\d/g,''),36)*79%2777%2328)*2-96,2),36)>>i&1)
```

#### Full test suite (Node.js)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVptd9o4Fv7eX6GTc6bAlGQIxk0cILNJmoaWpMkkbdndlhfZVrCLLVHZDmGmO3999soY2wTJkJn5MCdFj6Sr@/LceyV/ww84sLg7DXcps8lfHgnRPWr/FbSPd07xhHCPseoZoSHHXvXM5ZZHqm/cIOSuFVY72PcJD3w3dNBLdOaG8@r7yHQ9QqpXJORsyjw3xLT6gfHQIZxWb1zLwrbrefPqZ1iAcRdXeziMd0lW2NkLpjBrVB3t3bseDJXLw6pbaR9PMQ/IOxqWSwfW/qzGDhr7gTbRjFm9btXqNat2WJuRw9pc82r4cFYLtUcnqDPPOhjXJv7hway2f/CaH2JWJ41x7bs@qxFiHuiaTyazx/3J/mFpL4hMOFh5B@ldWx8aSLcaA73fHGl9DTX6jUFr9J9RbaA7GjJQs9VFxqButkYa6t0byBido1oLN1uoCX83@3XWMA0Da5qtj5pIG2nfTvvdb4ap6@TQ1/tt1PXvULPf1UfGwOi3htqgBv/UhmIvw2ia7X4XaejfxADA8DcQp8Y0s9lvmt37Nmmb2rfOsNVv2LD0@Mhu6ORj//1Q704af9S/G8Ou1bBanvHwZmSANOSdVR@86bf6Otbsw5HuvEWNb13n8pOv/dD7R6iJ9T9ax@hoALKGRl/3Xg9P/rw3HL2vm7ppON2@ASjdaxxh3Tf@1xj8i3UmnYFGNGvfatDT@5bZwUezNoh3Erzxmqg76vzZ7Wt28/6QG6hBDfK5b6DWwPhTo22vBcvB0tiYdJGO9NERao@PcMc6Mevffx3WzVp4EnywmoAyhhrRifb9ZHI7OLF0s4uurF9x0wjb8/qwCdJpwzppPVzbjaHhNgdnI2PWxNr0CLe@wRbooEuOhi1Q50gfXuCGY4SHQ2NwTLR@Z3A@1n8/IQ3rv8Mmubnw60jD2s4eJ1MPW6T8y94v46rVPrbELwSH5TJtW1/O2iXLwfwMwuQkLPXLlUrLqP/4QXeN/Urly1m/nHpokK30tffjqw2rlUqVqva68vOB8VP94ODgp7pWP6z8XN81Xlfr8cjxsftyvxLHHycBaqNSqfoCwX9sAv@oLf4OQhy6jDZfvCgnf8LYFxj6gnZOIJ4o@shmdKeKvuwsg3SnupNF3U4f9asJ3LPHEHkxdhHXgMxH7ToWneMgfLr4OgesTJwSDmLFk@RiiMkO9mOEans6Jl4MWBJJfpBbzgzP1cOUBeiCswdSIATYjWJPDYiZEN2FnJCFApbUCApIlSfRRHUn4UO1bk@xtzy@RPxTTCcLEy0oGNZJUdWdp9SZn8dN18J01bxSCZVy8YlLx88ydzIncG2yIvQKgtEAnbGIh1u56SmeBzNxzNWTpNNySGIxKiy0um4e4AXu7wTdgJRKfRPuM2oHZOFQS@vlAaEDrgIeRQhVHRJCf3IPuY0Hm6UWWIeBA6Jbhu0Yv0yNeRgIlfe/zB0kIjLOorGjPCILBFFcYcp4gcezCNSQO6YCNcvE3tpLOAiPzjgLAqWM3H1c0oZMG5z5HpnvmvNdkOB5m0eg7ogHIerAWVQGjDhIeI2VbnKGPWIz6mKaHV@qoDPs2yTHytK1KLYx6qVOvm5RAeFz1IPsc6@GUAi9bCc5BAyf96ICxwS0iNQ0WCTrOdi7h5ADJV9CLvIT8RV8ItAT9BZzJdcBgloEznmJqYo/AMPFMTPvyTGxdE2yKbucOe54RpS@AMPBzLUmmSZkyoIIBoecMWYXbuXhKUgD9Of7TO0QCSoe2gS6Y1EBiAEPQbiThIjkLgpiUht7RL2K57mwBOotjycFPYiovsDcLiIMsNujl5CrQklv8JhQcbT1akMC6kB5luZ/GZCYtpKo34iTBRkTrPv4OfaEuwHhYHu5S8a9kv2SCTkLb8pw55h7peekRKEXFFd7imPFgLcutZylqiUGi0GdJDS2Zc940k0UUqJUuIBYLCksV0ysOo49nmGu9L5kOONZWem1tfwegaiJKesM5Ex8vphCzj2/MPbPfROKNB@ssI14sg2m02WhJbFlFIRPqaIqy4kLILr7Hi2V@bfKvrfYBemnCmmAvgX92uwfFJZLx0RpHMkNn@JSy2@spWFKYEaQQVJ75TxOqrW3kai@V@NbYuML8JmgqGK48FhkEcG0mbgy80sj4IJ5tuDXrNiSqEOAHDybSNYvdPkLIO0xyWd92eIcQ49VeEAORItuYKqHn5Sif8cJ4qPeM26rt4Oyaa34qG406EVEKQghvEBlzA52KY68ULF17hhKM0qPKrUtIKfgFliZODtC87yo5ulAgiDBMoul/LIC4FCIv0Q9gj1b0AAphu4yugty7Kb2Vlipg0PBKVmxJT@iSMFCgI/QPIFqvQDtV1G9irRnzEGN54D1IjC1hczF5NJxxw6CZpSqY0JAYjJ5id4FIqkXNCQCm96mqLZbxAzqEhrkViuqwYV9cnS7TTbtMM9knD4pVFTQOJbTKJO4HkAY8OKGLqcDO1rQVVmOMuagnQxgqRW7KNZKkGn5VwzrkULY3F40/FBfgbELGt531iSuKLfWNNiR5uwosbqw9MpVgSQgM29A5Wtv7k9dXFEpEbChGziF3aTAsILdZkmJHig3cT3welUPmYxmPiPbRFwBpQQsW4OORcErWAWCYg8WoxbHwXOzycpV2Ka80KUQgmFgcheyodoLLrFtcjYhuRvD7dLsJfZNAgNZ0ybRDJC8heMi4SK9el2LuaSXfm6evyRuUoDkSkC5gvKT5uo2YjGYpRMJwn0gfMqYJ7@a@luVwSWL@fs0M1SW/CX@fimuutRnuMKujdFn7CkzYnwPhoBOggK3AFAgLtszWBFtX2FuegSdLPlQJhafe8QsSNRXcGR0Tm1Vx7nBG2C6F5dzGY1KlHfFaJQ2LoUnYoyvvxY8K0RXF8sIROEGVyy9SJAuwRPuBRohgbU8gwT6geC0dlrnog9kttowrNsqXrOw314gFp2/2ocWqDgZzNzEMyQCxahFmVaknwWuR3xz2eNLnCgG3bsEisINcjFlORwPr16AFYm06QosBcXeGRRDw1DcpcRuvEaY1UKHvcaTVBLpqa89e0NPdC3IdKlc@RoP6gLz@lF0N0jIGK1dVGZnkGSqG2zbubrin1x3xIXPLZsX1VuACcRFb1alSNR5Q7j7sCTRdR/JFlYcWL6z63uuxVQ19Y1LafGV8o2HQdRnPgDcAF8I3kjTq2rx@JYrn4ckevktAqWVgsJyKMYU1UMLwNPbxWz8Fj/AuCXuBwsvom7xXLS@WSu5TRV7S@xcTSTZnIzhtw1HvAU@E89mSsmAPnxIobO0OFIo/ZYJ1xf5ehl4EomEP6ePM9sVR7eRCy3cdHutLPArtbJEkgSVPaVtt3YQEGC0XJkmxYnK@D32SZBXfhHnxROYI/wxvalf97ZFwR15JdWp7gi4G7pzs2cDSXDeOWQKjGfDXqdRoCpznqBAUXyyxa1RbgGPgTNLLzVlCqCAghKfMVUuj19LNmbqBSqXgwtQG7v56obZBd3aApP3XdWJeq6oA2x1K5rAwC0KLt1iUK5ckKlYQNJKUH2ymfrZ8C7EfpwbT1NDSZ0ZU59xolyETAU9S7LWJpcKmTVJ3/uK79TvRO@zoMdC/oNCAodripW9zd9FdlxvpjdvchUmqLTRl6NmbiDejcIQj1V6@kj8qbc5cj46ZB53XcxV0cJHxuJq7JRYKidLIfnbdCkuDBevd/GjV67TXf/IRTars6xEJCaLUQuLvUQ9h4RZ/ypdcwYNc3btXaSi6J4K2i76euRjxGMBpV4ptaGYMXUnJEvaUtinqe/SYPmBgES6FLChYPk0LXi6@zQVhdF6ibEhoj495iqIbTLgZxw9OjjRucSG6U8qRpXM6WEvBNWLcnDljlEKpdmN/Lqj94D3CZU2B4qdedwenUDajJT9/PJTraeVseRyo@i7rl6OZxQ1VNITrmhBJlACk7yxKBfe8O4cA8S3OdOQKVuJGLTpcToGbfc4LWPZ5fTcy4sStKnRjmFPsrzqWMWpWkBMIDxKJPVcYYSJmXkCkMWE5ICOG5JESXKBBMBy8DT5unLbgO9BPMcPUjmik2yfot5H1BLfqipdcaV6kSl3CSjsf0R1s@mDtRiTvbVtp/3iqkkMiy8e5ZnhRb/yYg9mn2PLKWPUPo6/7n3VRvhLrY9eoRLa3T2G/79CZY7a6L4sfq9U4pFy/DP@sh8DS6jdRhz9isps8upVFZWuu6UKOkKltyfvLkvxjMpXWqo0X7xItih9pdfdo3hxNhHjv4g/kw@H9zwCDu0A2oL2n3lkz2PjMsysNP/6Pw)

#### Demo (Chrome)

**NB**: Due to inconsistencies in the implementation of `parseInt()` across browsers<sup>(1)</sup>, this is only guaranteed to work for all stations on Chrome.

```js
let f =

s=>"Bakerloo,Central,Circle,District,Hammersmith & City,Jubilee,Metropolitan,Northern,Piccadilly,Victoria,Waterloo & City".split`,`.filter((_,i)=>parseInt('7c1w0o741s3k39w22c020c080we80y3l0a8w0t3xhs2olc7g0km87w0176r8ao2e4g0q5w0eeb753mekwx1k18'.substr(" 5Kd5_9 5c4^5];`3]3 4]4^<`Y`0^5h3 9 ;<K 9^2b<`3 Wf9 9`E 0<a;< ; 9`;]2o4b99a33d5`; 3`3jB]Kj9b55e8m5]= KmS ;]K5`9^9]<_3^0 ;]3_3]3 99;b=]K 3 Xe95`9_Qd5_0o3b;];bKf=e=b3jH_<]4d; 3g:d45eT]J_5Kk4{2q9_Kc4c<l9vD`9; 9eIc2^D]<]5a3d8`5hF 4jKhLUm3|5]: ;a5{<> :^3d5t9]5l6_A~f9h5]5b5b9hK]9]: 5l4:a5m9}4^@oHkH^3e3c1c4nBf<bHa:w=b;]AsDl; K`H~K]3d;f8r9 4n9eV]9 <^9~3n=l<]9]5]5a9kK 5 5`: =g:aHcAb2q?_2b0tAsNc;]9]9_3e5e3qAkR^Ac5bK Mc?a;9t=y2_;]5b3_2e<vOd4_9i;^C`9w;a3p:a<j9]5 7Ke:_<3 9`5_Ga4h9t8_9^>e3]H^Eg5zAe4cZ_;ePGm2 3a3".replace(/./g,c=>c.repeat((n=c[C='charCodeAt']())<92||n-91))[C](parseInt(s.replace(/\W|\d/g,''),36)*79%2777%2328)*2-96,2),36)>>i&1)
```

```html
<select onclick="O.innerText=f(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text).join(', ')">
<option>-- Where do you want to go? --</option>
<option>Acton Town</option>
<option>Aldgate</option>
<option>Aldgate East</option>
<option>Alperton</option>
<option>Amersham</option>
<option>Angel</option>
<option>Archway</option>
<option>Arnos Grove</option>
<option>Arsenal</option>
<option>Baker Street</option>
<option>Balham</option>
<option>Bank</option>
<option>Barbican</option>
<option>Barking</option>
<option>Barkingside</option>
<option>Barons Court</option>
<option>Bayswater</option>
<option>Becontree</option>
<option>Belsize Park</option>
<option>Bermondsey</option>
<option>Bethnal Green</option>
<option>Blackfriars</option>
<option>Blackhorse Road</option>
<option>Bond Street</option>
<option>Borough</option>
<option>Boston Manor</option>
<option>Bounds Green</option>
<option>Bow Road</option>
<option>Brent Cross</option>
<option>Brixton</option>
<option>Bromley-by-Bow</option>
<option>Buckhurst Hill</option>
<option>Burnt Oak</option>
<option>Caledonian Road</option>
<option>Camden Town</option>
<option>Canada Water</option>
<option>Canary Wharf</option>
<option>Canning Town</option>
<option>Cannon Street</option>
<option>Canons Park</option>
<option>Chalfont & Latimer</option>
<option>Chalk Farm</option>
<option>Chancery Lane</option>
<option>Charing Cross</option>
<option>Chesham</option>
<option>Chigwell</option>
<option>Chiswick Park</option>
<option>Chorleywood</option>
<option>Clapham Common</option>
<option>Clapham North</option>
<option>Clapham South</option>
<option>Cockfosters</option>
<option>Colindale</option>
<option>Colliers Wood</option>
<option>Covent Garden</option>
<option>Croxley</option>
<option>Dagenham East</option>
<option>Dagenham Heathway</option>
<option>Debden</option>
<option>Dollis Hill</option>
<option>Ealing Broadway</option>
<option>Ealing Common</option>
<option>Earl's Court</option>
<option>East Acton</option>
<option>East Finchley</option>
<option>East Ham</option>
<option>East Putney</option>
<option>Eastcote</option>
<option>Edgware</option>
<option>Edgware Road</option>
<option>Elephant & Castle</option>
<option>Elm Park</option>
<option>Embankment</option>
<option>Epping</option>
<option>Euston</option>
<option>Euston Square</option>
<option>Fairlop</option>
<option>Farringdon</option>
<option>Finchley Central</option>
<option>Finchley Road</option>
<option>Finsbury Park</option>
<option>Fulham Broadway</option>
<option>Gants Hill</option>
<option>Gloucester Road</option>
<option>Golders Green</option>
<option>Goldhawk Road</option>
<option>Goodge Street</option>
<option>Grange Hill</option>
<option>Great Portland Street</option>
<option>Greenford</option>
<option>Green Park</option>
<option>Gunnersbury</option>
<option>Hainault</option>
<option>Hammersmith</option>
<option>Hampstead</option>
<option>Hanger Lane</option>
<option>Harlesden</option>
<option>Harrow & Wealdstone</option>
<option>Harrow-on-the-Hill</option>
<option>Hatton Cross</option>
<option>Heathrow Terminals 1, 2, 3</option>
<option>Heathrow Terminal 4</option>
<option>Heathrow Terminal 5</option>
<option>Hendon Central</option>
<option>High Barnet</option>
<option>Highbury & Islington</option>
<option>Highgate</option>
<option>High Street Kensington</option>
<option>Hillingdon</option>
<option>Holborn</option>
<option>Holland Park</option>
<option>Holloway Road</option>
<option>Hornchurch</option>
<option>Hounslow Central</option>
<option>Hounslow East</option>
<option>Hounslow West</option>
<option>Hyde Park Corner</option>
<option>Ickenham</option>
<option>Kennington</option>
<option>Kensal Green</option>
<option>Kensington (Olympia)</option>
<option>Kentish Town</option>
<option>Kenton</option>
<option>Kew Gardens</option>
<option>Kilburn</option>
<option>Kilburn Park</option>
<option>Kingsbury</option>
<option>King's Cross St. Pancras</option>
<option>Knightsbridge</option>
<option>Ladbroke Grove</option>
<option>Lambeth North</option>
<option>Lancaster Gate</option>
<option>Latimer Road</option>
<option>Leicester Square</option>
<option>Leyton</option>
<option>Leytonstone</option>
<option>Liverpool Street</option>
<option>London Bridge</option>
<option>Loughton</option>
<option>Maida Vale</option>
<option>Manor House</option>
<option>Mansion House</option>
<option>Marble Arch</option>
<option>Marylebone</option>
<option>Mile End</option>
<option>Mill Hill East</option>
<option>Monument</option>
<option>Moorgate</option>
<option>Moor Park</option>
<option>Morden</option>
<option>Mornington Crescent</option>
<option>Neasden</option>
<option>Newbury Park</option>
<option>North Acton</option>
<option>North Ealing</option>
<option>North Greenwich</option>
<option>North Harrow</option>
<option>North Wembley</option>
<option>Northfields</option>
<option>Northolt</option>
<option>Northwick Park</option>
<option>Northwood</option>
<option>Northwood Hills</option>
<option>Notting Hill Gate</option>
<option>Oakwood</option>
<option>Old Street</option>
<option>Osterley</option>
<option>Oval</option>
<option>Oxford Circus</option>
<option>Paddington</option>
<option>Park Royal</option>
<option>Parsons Green</option>
<option>Perivale</option>
<option>Piccadilly Circus</option>
<option>Pimlico</option>
<option>Pinner</option>
<option>Plaistow</option>
<option>Preston Road</option>
<option>Putney Bridge</option>
<option>Queen's Park</option>
<option>Queensbury</option>
<option>Queensway</option>
<option>Ravenscourt Park</option>
<option>Rayners Lane</option>
<option>Redbridge</option>
<option>Regent's Park</option>
<option>Richmond</option>
<option>Rickmansworth</option>
<option>Roding Valley</option>
<option>Royal Oak</option>
<option>Ruislip</option>
<option>Ruislip Gardens</option>
<option>Ruislip Manor</option>
<option>Russell Square</option>
<option>St. James's Park</option>
<option>St. John's Wood</option>
<option>St. Paul's</option>
<option>Seven Sisters</option>
<option>Shepherd's Bush</option>
<option>Shepherd's Bush Market</option>
<option>Sloane Square</option>
<option>Snaresbrook</option>
<option>South Ealing</option>
<option>South Harrow</option>
<option>South Kensington</option>
<option>South Kenton</option>
<option>South Ruislip</option>
<option>South Wimbledon</option>
<option>South Woodford</option>
<option>Southfields</option>
<option>Southgate</option>
<option>Southwark</option>
<option>Stamford Brook</option>
<option>Stanmore</option>
<option>Stepney Green</option>
<option>Stockwell</option>
<option>Stonebridge Park</option>
<option>Stratford</option>
<option>Sudbury Hill</option>
<option>Sudbury Town</option>
<option>Swiss Cottage</option>
<option>Temple</option>
<option>Theydon Bois</option>
<option>Tooting Bec</option>
<option>Tooting Broadway</option>
<option>Tottenham Court Road</option>
<option>Tottenham Hale</option>
<option>Totteridge & Whetstone</option>
<option>Tower Hill</option>
<option>Tufnell Park</option>
<option>Turnham Green</option>
<option>Turnpike Lane</option>
<option>Upminster</option>
<option>Upminster Bridge</option>
<option>Upney</option>
<option>Upton Park</option>
<option>Uxbridge</option>
<option>Vauxhall</option>
<option>Victoria</option>
<option>Walthamstow Central</option>
<option>Wanstead</option>
<option>Warren Street</option>
<option>Warwick Avenue</option>
<option>Waterloo</option>
<option>Watford</option>
<option>Wembley Central</option>
<option>Wembley Park</option>
<option>West Acton</option>
<option>West Brompton</option>
<option>West Finchley</option>
<option>West Ham</option>
<option>West Hampstead</option>
<option>West Harrow</option>
<option>West Kensington</option>
<option>West Ruislip</option>
<option>Westbourne Park</option>
<option>Westminster</option>
<option>White City</option>
<option>Whitechapel</option>
<option>Willesden Green</option>
<option>Willesden Junction</option>
<option>Wimbledon</option>
<option>Wimbledon Park</option>
<option>Wood Green</option>
<option>Wood Lane</option>
<option>Woodford</option>
<option>Woodside Park</option>
</select>
<pre id=O></pre>
```

<sub>*(1) [From the specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-parseint-string-radix): Let mathInt be the mathematical integer value that is represented by Z in radix-R notation [...]. **If R is not 2, 4, 8, 10, 16, or 32, then mathInt may be an implementation-dependent approximation** to the mathematical integer value that is represented by Z in radix-R notation.*</sub>

---

#### How?

Below is a step-by-step decoding example for the input `s = "St. James's Park"`.

**Step #1**

We first inflate the primary lookup table (from 503 to 2,328 bytes) by expanding all its padding characters. These characters are encoded with an ASCII code greater than 92, whereas payload data is using the range 48-90.

```js
tbl = " 5Kd5_9 5c4[...]"
  .replace(
    /./g, c =>
      c.repeat((n = c.charCodeAt()) < 92 || n - 91)
  )
```

**Step #2**

We remove all non-alphabetic characters from the input string:

```js
str = s.replace(/\W|\d/g, '')
```

which gives `"StJamessPark"`.

**Step #3**

We parse the resulting string as a base-36 quantity:

```js
id = parseInt(str, 36)
```

which gives `3793395908848905700` (this is the approximated result returned by [Chrome V8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrome_V8)).

**Step #4**

We compute the hash value:

```js
hash = id * 79 % 2777 % 2328
```

which gives `533`.

**NB**: Due to loss of precision, this result is not mathematically correct (it should be `184`). But the lookup table was -- of course -- built the same way, so that's the one we're expecting.

**Step #5**

We retrieve the ASCII code of the character at this position in the primary lookup table:

```js
code = tbl.charCodeAt(hash)
```

which gives `58` (this is the character `':'`).

**Step #6**

We use this value to extract a 2-character string from the secondary lookup table:

```js
msk36 = '7c1w0o74[...]'.substr(code * 2 - 96, 2)
```

which gives `0c`.

**Step #7**

We parse this string as a base-36 quantity:

```js
msk = parseInt(msk36, 36)
```

which gives `12`.

**Step #8**

Finally, we filter the station list according to the bits set in `msk`, starting with the least significant one:

```js
"Bakerloo,Central,Circle,District,[...]".split`,`.filter((_, i) => msk >> i & 1)
```

In our example, `msk` holds `12`, which is `00000001100` in binary. So we keep the 3rd and 4th stations, which leads to the final result: `[ 'Circle', 'District' ]`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan It doesn't? For me it returns `Northern`.

Comment: You can save 3 bytes by compressing the script using [RegPack](https://siorki.github.io/regPack.html).

Comment: @ThePirateBay (update) I saved 46 bytes by re-encoding the main data string, so it's not RegPack-friendly at all anymore.

Comment: Out of interest, what are the inconsistencies to which you refer?

Comment: @Neil They seem to handle the loss of precision differently. For instance, `parseInt('buckhursthill', 36)` gives `56116801307528970000` in Firefox and `56116801307528980000` in Chrome. The number of correct stations is 267 for Node.js/Chrome (100%), 224 for Firefox and 241 for Edge. (Of course, it doesn't mean that Chrome is right and the other ones are wrong. My code just happen to have been built on Node / V8.)

Comment: @Neil [From the specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-parseint-string-radix): _Let mathInt be the mathematical integer value that is represented by Z in radix-R notation [...]. **If R is not 2, 4, 8, 10, 16, or 32, then mathInt may be an implementation-dependent approximation** to the mathematical integer value that is represented by Z in radix-R notation._

Answer (score 5):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>2271</s> <s>2270</s> <s>2000</s> 1694 bytes

```
{x->val r=java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode("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")
var I=java.util.zip.Inflater()
I.setInput(r)
I.finished()
var o=ByteArray(1846)
I.inflate(o)
var v=String(o).split("~")
Regex("(-?[0-9]+)([A-Z]+)").findAll(v[1]).filter{x.hashCode()%2897==it.groupValues[1].toInt()}.map{it.groupValues[2].map{v[0].split("|")[it-'A']}}.first()}
```

### Beautified

```
{x->
    // Parses the data line into groups of <hashcode % 2897, and line numbers within the list below as letters
    val r = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode("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")
    var I = java.util.zip.Inflater()
    I.setInput(r)
    I.finished()
    var o = ByteArray(1846)
    I.inflate(o)
    var v= String(o).split("~")
    Regex("(-?[0-9]+)([A-Z]+)")
            // Finds all the groups
            .findAll(v[1])// Gets the right group
            .filter{ x.hashCode()%2897==it.groupValues[1].toInt()}
            // Gets each letter and turns it into a station name
            .map{
                it.groupValues[2].map{
                    v[0]
                            .split("|")[it-'A']}}.first()
}
```

### Test

```
var v:(String)->List<String> =
{x->val r=java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode("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")
var I=java.util.zip.Inflater()
I.setInput(r)
I.finished()
var o=ByteArray(1846)
I.inflate(o)
var v=String(o).split("~")
Regex("(-?[0-9]+)([A-Z]+)").findAll(v[1]).filter{x.hashCode()%2897==it.groupValues[1].toInt()}.map{it.groupValues[2].map{v[0].split("|")[it-'A']}}.first()}
data class TestData(val name: String, val lines: List<String>)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var items = listOf(
            TestData("Acton Town", listOf("District", "Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Aldgate", listOf("Circle", "Metropolitan")),
            TestData("Aldgate East", listOf("District", "Hammersmith & City")),
            TestData("Alperton", listOf("Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Amersham", listOf("Metropolitan")),
            TestData("Angel", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("Archway", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("Arnos Grove", listOf("Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Arsenal", listOf("Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Baker Street", listOf("Bakerloo", "Circle", "Hammersmith & City", "Jubilee", "Metropolitan")),
            TestData("Balham", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("Bank", listOf("Central", "Northern", "Waterloo & City")),
            TestData("Barbican", listOf("Circle", "Hammersmith & City", "Metropolitan")),
            TestData("Barking", listOf("District", "Hammersmith & City")),
            TestData("Barkingside", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Barons Court", listOf("District", "Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Bayswater", listOf("Circle", "District")),
            TestData("Becontree", listOf("District")),
            TestData("Belsize Park", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("Bermondsey", listOf("Jubilee")),
            TestData("Bethnal Green", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Blackfriars", listOf("Circle", "District")),
            TestData("Blackhorse Road", listOf("Victoria")),
            TestData("Bond Street", listOf("Central", "Jubilee")),
            TestData("Borough", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("Boston Manor", listOf("Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Bounds Green", listOf("Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Bow Road", listOf("District", "Hammersmith & City")),
            TestData("Brent Cross", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("Brixton", listOf("Victoria")),
            TestData("Bromley-by-Bow", listOf("District", "Hammersmith & City")),
            TestData("Buckhurst Hill", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Burnt Oak", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("Caledonian Road", listOf("Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Camden Town", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("Canada Water", listOf("Jubilee")),
            TestData("Canary Wharf", listOf("Jubilee")),
            TestData("Canning Town", listOf("Jubilee")),
            TestData("Cannon Street", listOf("Circle", "District")),
            TestData("Canons Park", listOf("Jubilee")),
            TestData("Chalfont & Latimer", listOf("Metropolitan")),
            TestData("Chalk Farm", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("Chancery Lane", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Charing Cross", listOf("Bakerloo", "Northern")),
            TestData("Chesham", listOf("Metropolitan")),
            TestData("Chigwell", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Chiswick Park", listOf("District")),
            TestData("Chorleywood", listOf("Metropolitan")),
            TestData("Clapham Common", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("Clapham North", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("Clapham South", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("Cockfosters", listOf("Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Colindale", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("Colliers Wood", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("Covent Garden", listOf("Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Croxley", listOf("Metropolitan")),
            TestData("Dagenham East", listOf("District")),
            TestData("Dagenham Heathway", listOf("District")),
            TestData("Debden", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Dollis Hill", listOf("Jubilee")),
            TestData("Ealing Broadway", listOf("Central", "District")),
            TestData("Ealing Common", listOf("District", "Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Earl's Court", listOf("District", "Piccadilly")),
            TestData("East Acton", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("East Finchley", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("East Ham", listOf("District", "Hammersmith & City")),
            TestData("East Putney", listOf("District")),
            TestData("Eastcote", listOf("Metropolitan", "Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Edgware", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("Edgware Road", listOf("Bakerloo", "Circle", "District", "Hammersmith & City")),
            TestData("Elephant & Castle", listOf("Bakerloo", "Northern")),
            TestData("Elm Park", listOf("District")),
            TestData("Embankment", listOf("Bakerloo", "Circle", "District", "Northern")),
            TestData("Epping", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Euston", listOf("Northern", "Victoria")),
            TestData("Euston Square", listOf("Circle", "Hammersmith & City", "Metropolitan")),
            TestData("Fairlop", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Farringdon", listOf("Circle", "Hammersmith & City", "Metropolitan")),
            TestData("Finchley Central", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("Finchley Road", listOf("Jubilee", "Metropolitan")),
            TestData("Finsbury Park", listOf("Piccadilly", "Victoria")),
            TestData("Fulham Broadway", listOf("District")),
            TestData("Gants Hill", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Gloucester Road", listOf("Circle", "District", "Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Golders Green", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("Goldhawk Road", listOf("Circle", "Hammersmith & City")),
            TestData("Goodge Street", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("Grange Hill", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Great Portland Street", listOf("Circle", "Hammersmith & City", "Metropolitan")),
            TestData("Greenford", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Green Park", listOf("Jubilee", "Piccadilly", "Victoria")),
            TestData("Gunnersbury", listOf("District")),
            TestData("Hainault", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Hammersmith", listOf("Circle", "District", "Hammersmith & City", "Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Hampstead", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("Hanger Lane", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Harlesden", listOf("Bakerloo")),
            TestData("Harrow & Wealdstone", listOf("Bakerloo")),
            TestData("Harrow-on-the-Hill", listOf("Metropolitan")),
            TestData("Hatton Cross", listOf("Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Heathrow Terminals 1, 2, 3", listOf("Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Heathrow Terminal 4", listOf("Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Heathrow Terminal 5", listOf("Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Hendon Central", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("High Barnet", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("Highbury & Islington", listOf("Victoria")),
            TestData("Highgate", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("High Street Kensington", listOf("Circle", "District")),
            TestData("Hillingdon", listOf("Metropolitan", "Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Holborn", listOf("Central", "Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Holland Park", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Holloway Road", listOf("Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Hornchurch", listOf("District")),
            TestData("Hounslow Central", listOf("Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Hounslow East", listOf("Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Hounslow West", listOf("Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Hyde Park Corner", listOf("Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Ickenham", listOf("Metropolitan", "Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Kennington", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("Kensal Green", listOf("Bakerloo")),
            TestData("Kensington (Olympia)", listOf("District")),
            TestData("Kentish Town", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("Kenton", listOf("Bakerloo")),
            TestData("Kew Gardens", listOf("District")),
            TestData("Kilburn", listOf("Jubilee")),
            TestData("Kilburn Park", listOf("Bakerloo")),
            TestData("Kingsbury", listOf("Jubilee")),
            TestData("King's Cross St. Pancras", listOf("Circle", "Hammersmith & City", "Metropolitan", "Northern", "Piccadilly", "Victoria")),
            TestData("Knightsbridge", listOf("Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Ladbroke Grove", listOf("Circle", "Hammersmith & City")),
            TestData("Lambeth North", listOf("Bakerloo")),
            TestData("Lancaster Gate", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Latimer Road", listOf("Circle", "Hammersmith & City")),
            TestData("Leicester Square", listOf("Northern", "Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Leyton", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Leytonstone", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Liverpool Street", listOf("Central", "Circle", "Hammersmith & City", "Metropolitan")),
            TestData("London Bridge", listOf("Jubilee", "Northern")),
            TestData("Loughton", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Maida Vale", listOf("Bakerloo")),
            TestData("Manor House", listOf("Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Mansion House", listOf("Circle", "District")),
            TestData("Marble Arch", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Marylebone", listOf("Bakerloo")),
            TestData("Mile End", listOf("Central", "District", "Hammersmith & City")),
            TestData("Mill Hill East", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("Monument", listOf("Circle", "District")),
            TestData("Moorgate", listOf("Circle", "Hammersmith & City", "Metropolitan", "Northern")),
            TestData("Moor Park", listOf("Metropolitan")),
            TestData("Morden", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("Mornington Crescent", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("Neasden", listOf("Jubilee")),
            TestData("Newbury Park", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("North Acton", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("North Ealing", listOf("Piccadilly")),
            TestData("North Greenwich", listOf("Jubilee")),
            TestData("North Harrow", listOf("Metropolitan")),
            TestData("North Wembley", listOf("Bakerloo")),
            TestData("Northfields", listOf("Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Northolt", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Northwick Park", listOf("Metropolitan")),
            TestData("Northwood", listOf("Metropolitan")),
            TestData("Northwood Hills", listOf("Metropolitan")),
            TestData("Notting Hill Gate", listOf("Central", "Circle", "District")),
            TestData("Oakwood", listOf("Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Old Street", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("Osterley", listOf("Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Oval", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("Oxford Circus", listOf("Bakerloo", "Central", "Victoria")),
            TestData("Paddington", listOf("Bakerloo", "Circle", "District", "Hammersmith & City")),
            TestData("Park Royal", listOf("Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Parsons Green", listOf("District")),
            TestData("Perivale", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Piccadilly Circus", listOf("Bakerloo", "Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Pimlico", listOf("Victoria")),
            TestData("Pinner", listOf("Metropolitan")),
            TestData("Plaistow", listOf("District", "Hammersmith & City")),
            TestData("Preston Road", listOf("Metropolitan")),
            TestData("Putney Bridge", listOf("District")),
            TestData("Queen's Park", listOf("Bakerloo")),
            TestData("Queensbury", listOf("Jubilee")),
            TestData("Queensway", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Ravenscourt Park", listOf("District")),
            TestData("Rayners Lane", listOf("Metropolitan", "Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Redbridge", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Regent's Park", listOf("Bakerloo")),
            TestData("Richmond", listOf("District")),
            TestData("Rickmansworth", listOf("Metropolitan")),
            TestData("Roding Valley", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Royal Oak", listOf("Circle", "Hammersmith & City")),
            TestData("Ruislip", listOf("Metropolitan", "Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Ruislip Gardens", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Ruislip Manor", listOf("Metropolitan", "Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Russell Square", listOf("Piccadilly")),
            TestData("St. James's Park", listOf("Circle", "District")),
            TestData("St. John's Wood", listOf("Jubilee")),
            TestData("St. Paul's", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Seven Sisters", listOf("Victoria")),
            TestData("Shepherd's Bush", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Shepherd's Bush Market", listOf("Circle", "Hammersmith & City")),
            TestData("Sloane Square", listOf("Circle", "District")),
            TestData("Snaresbrook", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("South Ealing", listOf("Piccadilly")),
            TestData("South Harrow", listOf("Piccadilly")),
            TestData("South Kensington", listOf("Circle", "District", "Piccadilly")),
            TestData("South Kenton", listOf("Bakerloo")),
            TestData("South Ruislip", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("South Wimbledon", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("South Woodford", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Southfields", listOf("District")),
            TestData("Southgate", listOf("Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Southwark", listOf("Jubilee")),
            TestData("Stamford Brook", listOf("District")),
            TestData("Stanmore", listOf("Jubilee")),
            TestData("Stepney Green", listOf("District", "Hammersmith & City")),
            TestData("Stockwell", listOf("Northern", "Victoria")),
            TestData("Stonebridge Park", listOf("Bakerloo")),
            TestData("Stratford", listOf("Central", "Jubilee")),
            TestData("Sudbury Hill", listOf("Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Sudbury Town", listOf("Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Swiss Cottage", listOf("Jubilee")),
            TestData("Temple", listOf("Circle", "District")),
            TestData("Theydon Bois", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Tooting Bec", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("Tooting Broadway", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("Tottenham Court Road", listOf("Central", "Northern")),
            TestData("Tottenham Hale", listOf("Victoria")),
            TestData("Totteridge & Whetstone", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("Tower Hill", listOf("Circle", "District")),
            TestData("Tufnell Park", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("Turnham Green", listOf("District", "Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Turnpike Lane", listOf("Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Upminster", listOf("District")),
            TestData("Upminster Bridge", listOf("District")),
            TestData("Upney", listOf("District")),
            TestData("Upton Park", listOf("District", "Hammersmith & City")),
            TestData("Uxbridge", listOf("Metropolitan", "Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Vauxhall", listOf("Victoria")),
            TestData("Victoria", listOf("Circle", "District", "Victoria")),
            TestData("Walthamstow Central", listOf("Victoria")),
            TestData("Wanstead", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Warren Street", listOf("Northern", "Victoria")),
            TestData("Warwick Avenue", listOf("Bakerloo")),
            TestData("Waterloo", listOf("Bakerloo", "Jubilee", "Northern", "Waterloo & City")),
            TestData("Watford", listOf("Metropolitan")),
            TestData("Wembley Central", listOf("Bakerloo")),
            TestData("Wembley Park", listOf("Jubilee", "Metropolitan")),
            TestData("West Acton", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("West Brompton", listOf("District")),
            TestData("West Finchley", listOf("Northern")),
            TestData("West Ham", listOf("District", "Hammersmith & City", "Jubilee")),
            TestData("West Hampstead", listOf("Jubilee")),
            TestData("West Harrow", listOf("Metropolitan")),
            TestData("West Kensington", listOf("District")),
            TestData("West Ruislip", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Westbourne Park", listOf("Circle", "Hammersmith & City")),
            TestData("Westminster", listOf("Circle", "District", "Jubilee")),
            TestData("White City", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Whitechapel", listOf("District", "Hammersmith & City")),
            TestData("Willesden Green", listOf("Jubilee")),
            TestData("Willesden Junction", listOf("Bakerloo")),
            TestData("Wimbledon", listOf("District")),
            TestData("Wimbledon Park", listOf("District")),
            TestData("Wood Green", listOf("Piccadilly")),
            TestData("Wood Lane", listOf("Circle", "Hammersmith & City")),
            TestData("Woodford", listOf("Central")),
            TestData("Woodside Park", listOf("Northern"))
    )

    var good = 0
    var bad = 0

    for (item in items) {
        var out = v(item.name);
        if (item.lines == out) {
            good++
        } else {
            bad++
        }
    }
    println("Results: G $good B $bad")
}
```

### Edits

Removed unneeded pipe separators -270 bytes

Compressed with zip tools -306 bytes

Comment: TIL: Woodside Park is 1337.

Comment: Looking to use Java's zip tools to compress the string, should get the byte count down a bit more

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>2309</s> <s>2301</s> 2218 bytes

```python
lambda I,p="Woods|Woodf|Wood L|Wo|Wimbledon |Wim|Willesden J|Wi|Whitec|Wh|Westm|Westb|West R|West K|West Har|West Hamp|West H|West F|West B|Wes|Wembley P|We|Watf|Wat|Warw|War|Wan|W|Vi|V|Ux|Upt|Upn|Upminster |U|Turnp|Tur|Tu|Tow|Totter|Tottenham H|Tot|Tooting Br|To|Th|T|Sw|Sudbury T|Su|Str|Ston|Sto|Ste|Stan|Sta|St. P|St. Jo|St|Southw|Southg|Southf|South Wo|South W|South R|South Kent|South K|South H|So|Sn|Sl|Shepherd's Bush |Sh|S|Rus|Ruislip M|Ruislip |Ru|Roy|Ro|Rick|Ri|Reg|Re|Ray|R|Queensw|Queens|Q|Pu|Pr|Pl|Pin|Pim|Pi|Pe|Pars|Par|P|Ox|Ov|Os|Ol|O|Not|Northwood |Northwo|Northw|Northo|Northf|North W|North H|North G|North E|No|New|N|Morn|Mor|Moorg|Moo|Mo|Mill|Mi|Mary|Mar|Mans|Man|M|Lou|Lo|Li|Leytons|Ley|Le|Lat|Lan|Lam|L|Kn|Kings|Kin|Kilburn |Ki|Kew|Kento|Kent|Kensi|Kens|K|I|Hy|Hounslow W|Hounslow E|Hou|Hor|Hollo|Holl|Ho|Hil|Highg|Highb|High S|Hi|Hen|Heathrow Terminals|Heathrow Terminal 5|He|Hat|Harrow-|Harr|Har|Han|Hamp|Ham|H|Gu|Greenf|Gree|Gre|Gr|Goo|Goldh|Go|Gl|G|Fu|Fins|Finchley R|Fi|Far|F|Euston |Eu|Ep|Em|Elm|El|Edgware |Ed|Eastc|East P|East H|East F|Eas|Ear|Ealing C|E|Do|De|Dagenham H|D|Cr|Cov|Coll|Col|Co|Clapham S|Clapham N|Cl|Cho|Chis|Chi|Che|Char|Chan|Chalk|Ch|Cano|Canno|Cann|Canar|Can|Cam|C|Bur|Bu|Bro|Bri|Br|Bow|Bou|Bos|Bor|Bo|Blackh|Bl|Bet|Ber|Bel|Be|Bay|Baro|Barkings|Bark|Bar|Ban|Bal|B|Ars|Arn|Ar|An|Am|Alp|Aldgate |Al|".split('|'):[j for i,j in enumerate('District|Piccadilly|Northern|Central|Circle|Metropolitan|Hammersmith & City|Jubilee|Bakerloo|Victoria|Waterloo & City'.split('|'))if[int(x,35)for x in'4 8 2A 2 1 1 7B 3N 1U 8 45 2A 8 1 W 3N 5I 4 1 8 4K 7B W 15C 7B EQ 8 EM F4 EM Y 1U 1 1 1 2 3 4 H 4 EM C 4 4 8 H 3N 2 2 3V 7B EQ 1U 3N 1 8 3N H 3N 2 1 8 4 8 7B J 2 2 8 H 2A 8 EM 2 Y 8 Y 2A 8 W 1 7B 8 Y 1 8 3N 7B 1 W 1U W EM 7D 8 1 2 9M M6 4 2 4 2 P W W W 8 2 7B W 3N 2 8 8 3N 4 4 3B W H 4 23 7B 8 H 2 7B 8 3R 3F 8 8 6 2A 8 7B 2A 2 3N I0 7B 3N 1 7B 4 1 7B 4 Y 2 2 2 2 1 2 8 A Y 4 EM H 4 4 2 2 2 2 W 7B 7B 8 4 2D 8 1 8 IC 37 8 4 2A 4 J 8 1 EO 4K 4 37 8 37 EQ 8 7W 1 7F 9M 4 Y 1 1U 4 8 3 3 9 3N 8 1 1 W 2 4 4 2 4 4 4 W 1 8 W 7F 8 4 W 3N H 3N 3N 3N 4 2 4 8 1U EM 4 1U 2 2 4 3V EM H 8 3N 4 1 H 3 8 1U 37 TL 4 E6 2 2 4 4 W 2 1U 1D 3'.split()][p.index([x for x in p if I.find(x)==0][0])]&2**i]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVVhb@I4EP0r1n5Yymqv2gLdsif1AwmBtEDLQtto1euHFAzx1sSRkywgzX/vvbFDddKJfe9NxmN7PB53i2OVmbzzvrn@512nu9d1Km6@FtefEmPWJTFvHIsphBK1e9VybXLBJqC1LNcyF7ewKclUJVcQSmRZ7Ry/OhYLLxMvcWpPxq5oLC8jLwELwLsdxRwWJWm1YQLsngnIKaEnRU/0eKDHogJyYKfyspJW0CM91DYvmAF6MHugwpCXPEt32Bc2YCqVb0XAQ/SQ0QMt97Ss16@1PQp81LSsLGByJkACKX@kwDlSZL7lEVqausr2XrZeNl4EStgYjS4anci8OpmNxlBaYgtNy0wWmbTrVimCuswEHLSkRV0CqtSqELMPCwYtzBGghVq9gWghtwAtUnjpZy1lXu4bpZ80r2luaa5prnJgB9Bc0jy1JRPN6f5A93/ovqR7Tfd0h3rdGYsjcluczEa9NF8bLzis17jRcaMRlO4kJtHM2JwJMHbLDNAM/QWiWWqPTABSBtGMpqYGaKpoKo@4l5IVoCl6ZIqQabqjKU1ymuBmS2ZA40LRvBNFE@zLVTeOmUrlmCZ0Q/GRYlPnpTZ7pP9hRmwCFtDaOAZRrCBqi@tmfnUslhCKZQ6kVWYx/UFaNGeqy/@7xCV8FCN3PA4M/OWUCcAS/FBAFNO4prHF3W2cMAE0RsXGRq8zMI01jWlU0wgvgWmV8TNawKQRFhxRVJcVP@KopqigaEeRZlC03u5TKzGwpigtq5VjdLeT2MuIBbCA5lcTUkRDQ0NJw3R7elZDCi2F5g@AGoEACnVa8PDyw7qDRSE6JsxUyQRIAKuDcib9BqYwzQ1Tw0wcwyEoS0gBHnlQU2ANoAAK8N4DXFdgSoC/KdDp6i2DUCArAE7JNgV4G0HKc1P75vqFDSYgBxBFA7yIAfp0YGkA3tFAF8B6m1Yo2UDTp/Oy0Ko6a1Gr/ffzb7ExVqivv4XKhczrnbQIPGsNVVlZtarw0FardI0eP/oHIbF2iGa02C1UdqUlzWRlTWGwqG8CrFHuFN7OZxGq6ki39avSkvN/k1ajB56wsLEq5T@VztNEtv6TWlttnlVenR2@di/bnOMBGbZ6oi86A9ERF/hdBaJ7Jy4e4etdsrsPZ8K@yxvRgw3/hKMScXEZshH9hC@aiVGP@RfPvXC/juhiRiycP4TwRjEv1eGxp2Yy4nlHjEGaYbcNgIhbF80TXTJYqoNN@oD7TnzO/N0sgS/OGMsmHH01dEfoiB8zMfuOVTsOc4zyD0f3p3H79v0SnGqXnZx8p@s3iH0kAhaiO3Kh330O8Lr6YebNt1MFWXsn@eUO0XEn410G8LiyxG6v02DC0W4P@HzefXETiu6Vdw1At84d3fM19PwIyF3ClSvGiE/ac/VADbiKXfx@cFJ9dy@JK0Gv4Z4rIRfyauR2ST7uwf/zgX1eLOKFoR3nwg26EzQlu@BJPg4JPUz5gN@b0J7blDtjKLqnjmy/PBfnKl/Lw9nzQZzaURRCbcTN@QYjZ4f29fW3l@dvL@2Xz50vX9TLe2HRwGJz1hqs@A8Z/mvPW@33fwE)

-6 thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder).

Too long...maybe it's golfable.

Comment: [1591 bytes](https://goo.gl/XQw6CT)

Comment: [1813 bytes](https://goo.gl/ThjrSW) Using a different lookup method.
[1498 bytes](https://goo.gl/xhwH5y) using @mdahmoune's encoding

Comment: [1498 bytes](https://goo.gl/76Y1C4) @EriktheOutgolfer I somehow copied the wrong link.. Here i is..

Comment: Forgot to remove duplicates (multiple stations with similar names and same lines):   [1708 bytes](https://goo.gl/bvbGgk) and [1434 bytes](https://goo.gl/LrGksk)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65416/discussion-between-erik-the-outgolfer-and-ascii-only).

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, <s>1785</s> <s>1780</s> 1471 bytes

```
eval(gzinflate(base64_decode('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')));
```

### Beautified

```
eval('
    // base64_decode(gzinflate()) long string into the further beautified:
    function a($b){
        $c="fe538,e0526,cb734,cd88,3156,0447,f267,b198,a498,22c02456,95b7,54317A,a5e246,6ee34,9061,17938,03323,2963,2ad7,de35,0101,5b423,cad9,d2415,1eb7,ee38,bdc8,f8334,7907,ec79,85034,26e1,6a87,9ca8,8747,1715,4875,acf5,5f023,6245,9596,81e7,ae91,78e07,8ab6,7cf1,c473,a2e6,cea7,b407,ee57,0748,16f7,a5d7,4028,fa26,f723,ddb3,a8c1,9035,7c513,36a38,07838,0a31,9b57,70d34,5c03,4d068,7d87,6130234,85507,adc3,68e0237,1ac1,f0079,6af246,8871,6fc246,4fe7,ad456,8e389,f743,a431,24d238,bad7,3f324,8e57,f901,793246,0641,a6a589,dd23,3541,0202348,4127,cb51,a070,38e0,0976,24b8,7918,7de8,5a07,6d17,2729,3197,89823,af268,9ff18,bce1,9bb8,0523,5468,9a78,67a8,3928,0ff68,83e7,c100,6713,9717,0ab0,fc53,3415,8a10,74c5,b0e246789,0288,16a24,cf60,bf71,66424,73778,ed21,2ff1,0e01246,dba57,f5b1,b500,c318,40923,ae71,7720,19e134,0d37,6a723,3662467,5e76,5f57,f997,4735,dab1,3451,c778,ef75,2ed6,7960,b038,1631,40a6,52b6,ae26,2e9123,ffe8,de27,3678,55d7,45a019,0cb0234,8f98,0893,6a21,10608,c349,98b6,1d734,a726,05d3,fae0,70c5,1991,6ef3,8f168,8771,f790,cc83,76e6,e241,8ec24,31168,7b61,6e268,26f8,7bc23,7a75,e6a1,f4b9,8661,6e724,cc023,ef11,1878,fe78,116238,d060,6081,9f07,9f21,de83,7c48,c295,7c33,d5d5,26334,42c79,e4f0,f3a15,7b58,bbf8,24f5,10423,c0c1,68b7,2aa7,c7c17,8349,a567,36d23,dcb7,b0d38,0bd8,2cf3,bef3,6123,b6b34,18468,c1b9,c51239,38e9,d881,b5579,a4c0,ccc057A,a8d6,a870,e0856,df31,ed43,f277,287345,55e5,b476,bb93,8931,f2424,49d235,70b1,45634,f0e5,7f80,62b3,7ca3,0f18,a8624,6361,3847";
        $d=["Bakerloo","Central","Circle","District","Hammersmith & City","Jubilee","Metropolitan","Northern","Piccadilly","Victoria","Waterloo & City"];
        $e=substr(md5($b), 21, 3);
        if($e=="ddb" && $b[0] == "H") // hard-coded Heathrow Terminals 1, 2, 3 here
            return $d[8];
        foreach(explode(",", $c) as $f)
            if(substr($f, 0, 3) == $e)
                foreach(str_split(substr($f, 3)) as $g)
                    echo $d[hexdec($g)]."\n";
    }
');
```

### Explanation

To distinguish the station name with as few as many characters, I fiddled a little and found out that if I took the 22nd, 23rd and 24th character of the MD5 hash, it would be unique except for ONE collision: `ddb` could stand for `Heathrow Terminals 1, 2, 3` as well as for `Dagenham Heathway`.

To refer to the 11 tube line names, I just use a hexidecimal digit from 0 through A.

Then I created a comma separated list of the MD5 hash substrings, with the corresponding tube line digits next to it. But I did leave out `Heathrow Terminals 1, 2, 3` from the list to avoid the collision.

Example: `fe538` means that whatever station who's md5'd name has the characters `fe5` on the 22nd, 23rd and 24th place, runs the tube lines referred to by `3` and `8`. Meaning `Acton Town` runs tube lines `District` and `Piccadilly`.

Then I wrote a simple function that checks the input. MD5 hashes it. Takes the 22nd, 23rd and 24th character. Matches it against the list that I created. And shows the corresponding tube names. With the expection of `ddb` off course, which is hardcoded to `Piccadilly`, when the given string starts with an `H`.

### Edits

- Replaced `array()` with `[]` for -5 chars
- Used gzdeflated and base64_encoded my code, so I can now use `eval(gzinflate(base64_decode()))` for -309 chars

Comment: The MD5 hash digits are also hexadecimal. It should be doable to get the 12 bits that reside in the three characters into 2 ascii characters. This could reduce 1 character per station. But the code to do this might outweigh this idea...

Answer (score 3):

## [Cinnamon Gum](https://github.com/quartata/cinnamon-gum), 2100 bytes

Hexdump:

```
0000000: 6c95 594d 77db 3a0e fd2b 5ab9 33e7 3873  l.YMw.:..+Z.3.8s
0000010: ce7c ccaa ab3a 6d93 d797 be66 92bc 7a0d  .|...:m....f..z.
0000020: 4b88 c563 8af4 8054 1ccd af1f 1066 484a  K..c...T.....fHJ
0000030: 4aec 7417 5f80 e025 085c 92ca a7da 5b53  J.t._..%.\....[S
0000040: 3dd8 8359 7c56 ce93 aafd f256 d535 344a  =..Y|V.....V.54J
0000050: ebe1 e327 dd6c c1e3 e252 51ad 71f9 1d3d  ...'.l...RQ.q..=
0000060: d9bd d5ca 8379 b155 5fc0 f93c f81a ba0e  .....y.U_..<....
0000070: c975 cab7 1598 a6ba 543e 84d9 23f1 448b  .u......T>..#.D.
0000080: 3274 706b a15b 8c83 9a2d eac5 1f96 7c8b  2tpk.[...-....|.
0000090: c43f a96e 0f30 9480 b1ae ba22 fb84 a360  .?.n.0....."...`
00000a0: e4d0 802e a115 ec90 aa7b 4f88 7e21 3fb4  .........{O.~!?.
00000b0: b5cb b890 d758 2ebf f51b a571 b2ca 1568  .....X.....q...h
00000c0: 2699 09ac c0ec 1697 683c 815e bea0 cb35  &.......h<.^...5
00000d0: 7889 9f82 b11f 6d54 0d66 7162 c6e9 4cb4  x.....mT.fqb..L.
00000e0: 5366 7b26 95d1 cba9 065f 6804 cc1a 575d  Sf{&....._h...W]
00000f0: da9e 8a9d 18e5 6270 8740 f185 cd8b d3c7  ......bp.@......
0000100: 15d6 d684 1c2d 0a48 3bf5 3fac 6e79 a662  .....-.H;.?.ny.b
0000110: dd48 9d35 8dc3 6111 f3c4 906f 0d68 de0d  .H.5..a....o.h..
0000120: 4493 c968 a877 8fa4 80dc 6c36 b1b5 961c  D..h.w....l6....
0000130: 5677 169a c54f 062d bb7e 5c71 e8b8 5729  Vw...O.-.~\q..W)
0000140: b969 1a4b b6df b605 15eb 42d1 7e07 6369  .i.K......B.~.ci
0000150: b4e3 b667 8291 ce08 3fc8 74e7 324b 3c71  ...g....?.t.2K<q
0000160: 7549 d6b9 622e 52cf 3c59 c194 6ca7 71b8  uI..b.R.<Y..l.q.
0000170: d80c 171c f75c c89e 97db 93f3 d535 33c9  .....\.......53.
0000180: 29ea 8967 fa01 457a 2f41 6363 8d02 2354  )..g..Ez/Acc..#T
0000190: 0bfa 6cea 1a8c 3d5a f81b 68a0 92ba 4b1b  ..l...=Z..h...K.
00001a0: 1240 1aaa 750b f458 8286 0b46 c68f 406b  .@..u..X...F..@k
00001b0: 52c6 27db c456 6b9c 1440 1ed1 827e b44c  R.'..Vk..@...~.L
00001c0: 7b51 dd80 57bc d651 e38a 7d57 7d05 4abd  {Q..W..Q..}W}.J.
00001d0: 2298 a991 061e 6172 b532 4a81 9064 3a77  ".....ar.2J..d:w
00001e0: 6631 0a67 bac0 a0da 1eb0 c821 03ee a0ea  f1.g.......!....
00001f0: dd91 65a6 de5a d238 1cac 6d26 0134 ec39  ..e..Z.8..m&.4.9
0000200: 2a37 49d7 d994 c88c 0b30 87ef 6d3f 822d  *7I......0..m?.-
0000210: d7b6 751e c98d b688 2731 0d68 2c3d b556  ..u.....'1.h,=.V
0000220: ec56 ad99 4a09 3f85 2abb 026a c645 cad9  .V..J.?.*..j.E..
0000230: 7866 e263 d29f 618b 8669 8c35 36c3 d708  xf.c..a..i.56...
0000240: 5ef4 319b 70d3 14cd f839 b070 527d 6927  ^.1.p....9.pR}i'
0000250: bf80 0ee9 e742 8626 8c8d be79 fba3 43cc  .....B.&...y..C.
0000260: d42b 7ac2 1ea4 3f9c 129c c0b7 92b3 2551  .+z...?.......%Q
0000270: 11e8 ab32 75ab b110 7481 b979 ce74 92b8  ...2u...t..y.t..
0000280: ddf6 de60 5eac 80b5 f538 4ada 8846 b33d  ...`^....8J..F.=
0000290: 0015 bb12 01e9 b1d9 a170 8681 46ae 0869  .........p..F..i
00002a0: 804b 9e57 e3bc 74d9 a79b d4e3 976e 0366  .K.W..t......n.f
00002b0: d7a1 f16f 4f97 87ef f79c f89c b1de f9a2  ...oO...........
00002c0: 5497 4983 c4c0 ddfb df1e 08df 7fc0 7c05  T.I...........|.
00002d0: c5f3 ef53 7c6e d6d0 888d 35bf 1023 6e60  ...S|n....5..#n`
00002e0: 1583 2476 d922 b98d c536 1bec 363d 0d92  ..$v."...6..6=..
00002f0: a3a2 f8f3 cabe f6e1 b4cd b599 f278 05c6  .............x..
0000300: bbb1 8a5e 69db d718 7a51 a6cc 2a36 2fc7  ...^i...zQ..*6/.
0000310: 2bab 1ba4 7834 24ca 02b7 70d8 c9f8 5339  +...x4$...p...S9
0000320: 604f db6c 31ea 6511 80c0 303c a645 085c  `O.l1.e...0<.E.\
0000330: aaec a221 1f6a ef4e b050 7cb4 d494 01d1  ...!.j.N.P|.....
0000340: 8cc4 78f9 5aea ae7a 6390 24bf 396d d7a0  ..x.Z..zc.$.9m..
0000350: 0cf4 daa7 6005 81c5 7bca becc 22db f7ce  ....`...{..."...
0000360: 2314 7276 1dd6 4f23 7d67 8c34 ba06 4daa  #.rv..O#}g.4..M.
0000370: f800 913d 70e7 ac11 7413 8a17 a7c6 0b6b  ...=p...t......k
0000380: 2e38 e685 e4b2 cc08 db3d 0f88 c745 4147  .8.......=...EAG
0000390: c42f 847d 40ea 9401 edaa bf2f ab7f 2cab  ./.}@....../..,.
00003a0: 7f9e f4aa fe75 dafc efb1 d934 d6cc 8bfd  .....u.....4....
00003b0: 5a6d db6a 0564 d08f 4129 ef45 f59b 0b12  Zm.j.d..A).E....
00003c0: 5a5e 1cc4 2a77 e991 7fac 8fea 7734 2e8e  Z^..*w......w4..
00003d0: 989e c621 23b1 4ddf d2b9 6bab 3796 92d6  ...!#.M...k.7...
00003e0: 4e4c 5287 523f d12e a03d 40ec d591 3771  NLR.R?...=@...7q
00003f0: 17f7 54b7 450d d9de 3876 4f59 c8fe d916  ..T.E...8vOY....
0000400: a4f8 55c3 1a27 86a1 4121 c3a7 0719 a4d2  ..U..'..A!......
0000410: f65b bd93 73ed cd75 7296 4ccc 52ca 2263  .[..s..ur.L.R."c
0000420: 2e5d 4253 51e5 7c56 7ff9 a187 6eaf e0af  .]BSQ.|V....n...
0000430: 7949 6cf5 cab5 e33b 95a0 7614 e310 0f6a  yIl....;..v....j
0000440: 570c 559a f738 dfa4 e26f 5952 3194 e796  W.U..8...oYR1...
0000450: 56cc 7e8c 7c70 c72a e64d ff1b 0f30 3581  V.~.|p.*.M...05.
0000460: 7bb7 32a4 63e2 d5ee ffdd 7031 79b7 21c5  {.2.c.....p1y.!.
0000470: 3a55 e6f4 069a 0dd9 1dc6 37d3 89d9 d8b5  :U........7.....
0000480: db20 0332 515a 0bc3 a606 91d9 2bf0 b9cd  . .2QZ......+...
0000490: e32d f0bc 76de a08a 321d 0fac f942 82d3  .-..v...2....B..
00004a0: 505c 16e2 4f11 8a8c a927 a4bd b57a fa50  P\..O....'...z.P
00004b0: 78b7 b6de 58e9 e695 2429 8969 daff 9bf0  x...X...$).i....
00004c0: cc28 597c 07d5 40f5 1374 a156 f2ea a8b8  .(Y|..@..t.V....
00004d0: bc5d 99e6 003b 654d 344c 5a98 adb4 d158  .]...;eM4LZ....X
00004e0: 85d7 6c11 9c06 8d1b 6bca e08a bdbe 98a4  ..l.....k.......
00004f0: fda7 b539 b86b 397c a4fd 7221 7fb7 a697  ...9.k9|..r!....
0000500: 2bc7 8c87 b524 1af4 cb45 2743 8f45 5eda  +....$...E'C.E^.
0000510: 1996 8b6c e146 d2a1 22d8 e86a 3405 af3f  ...l.F.."..j4..?
0000520: 105c 83a9 77f8 f741 f472 a44d e25d dc1d  .\..w..A.r.M.]..
0000530: 3376 bc97 1659 8fb8 b4fe 41d5 6d0e 2cf8  3v...Y....A.m.,.
0000540: f160 19f1 8d96 3576 bc1f 434e bcc0 8f0a  .`....5v..CN....
0000550: 75e3 66f1 adf6 6322 f9d9 310f 3d7b 7864  u.f...c"..1.={xd
0000560: 5876 ca4d 8dde f39a c434 6aaf e574 ebf8  Xv.M.....4j..t..
0000570: b528 b10b 763f 7433 bb91 fc08 8d16 9656  .(..v?t3.......V
0000580: fa3d 812e 3c9e c3ed a20a f1fb e2f9 15e7  .=..<...........
0000590: cd8a 720b 4d13 b5f6 d72e ca22 ee77 7628  ..r.M......".wv(
00005a0: 4f0a 419d 35f1 0a96 e5f4 1649 31bd dce5  O.A.5......I1...
00005b0: 79c8 8c62 194d 755a d576 91d9 2a63 a64f  y..b.MuZ.v..*c.O
00005c0: d25b 0d3c cdd9 47fa 2d21 7bc5 77f7 3880  .[.<..G.-!{.w.8.
00005d0: bc37 a25e 64ce ffe9 11cd 0737 917c 4147  .7.^d......7.|AG
00005e0: 9a1f a1e2 8df5 f10e 9e18 a9c3 bb69 fc50  .............i.P
00005f0: 60cb 6098 9a5c a5de 3cff eeb0 890a 9f02  `.`..\..<.......
0000600: e216 8d9f 91b9 e36e e8ac 698a f85c b41d  .......n..i..\..
0000610: 301b 11f7 d132 ef6c d8e8 a073 1a33 55d9  0....2.l...s.3U.
0000620: 41f9 4871 4adc ef7a e5b4 dabf c138 d9d3  A.HqJ..z.....8..
0000630: 399a a247 5ce4 f4c4 68e7 50eb 9783 a3b0  9..G\...h.P.....
0000640: 8413 f41b 74e8 e2d2 6752 270e b6e5 7d92  ....t...gR'...}.
0000650: 1778 da93 e3d1 dbeb 0f99 cb3d f2a6 54f7  .x.........=..T.
0000660: 4a9e f5b9 a4ee 5bdc b748 0d47 58f5 2e0b  J.....[..H.GX...
0000670: f704 e725 d0ee e40d 9fd9 6a0b 06e3 32e6  ...%......j...2.
0000680: 540d a36e 43d6 eef2 24b6 7f55 f118 cfca  T..nC...$..U....
0000690: 36c5 4fdc 2297 aff9 96bd 1dd1 b82f 131e  6.O."......../..
00006a0: 6b15 f4b2 29af 5d62 90d4 0639 29fd 9390  k...).]b...9)...
00006b0: a605 0a28 e7ce 94c5 8173 576c 0d74 a24d  ...(.....sWl.t.M
00006c0: 2b49 45b1 9560 3a4b 5838 e2de e030 d192  +IE..`:KX8...0..
00006d0: 3752 ef6d bd93 2f47 f377 34db 0c1e 1b6a  7R.m../G.w4....j
00006e0: dc3f 6c21 f0e5 c296 69ee be09 3d2e 8a5d  .?l!....i...=..]
00006f0: 2c27 e172 a52c f183 72e1 4b89 f7b0 cd2b  ,'.r.,..r.K....+
0000700: 78c0 6eaf e795 f0d0 e220 3714 ab72 793e  x.n...... 7..ry>
0000710: 582b 67c4 0aeb 9cfe 08e6 9772 61f1 5e6e  X+g........ra.^n
0000720: d1c7 cf33 226b 6915 af78 5d83 c65c f482  ...3"ki..x]..\..
0000730: 4b46 c26b ad45 2f77 b032 fa01 4916 3f27  KF.k.E/w.2..I.?'
0000740: df3f 1ad4 7afc dd98 5192 6926 7b95 3324  .?..z...Q.i&{.3$
0000750: 1e7b b5c3 a3f4 1586 3ff7 9d32 a129 d3b0  .{......?..2.)..
0000760: 0c65 514e 1683 43f9 9379 0b95 33f5 f1e7  .eQN..C..y..3...
0000770: b314 c0db 9afb 13fa e716 b4ce 397a f963  ............9z.c
0000780: d663 c963 0dda f3a2 9d2f 5e4d 8531 ac20  .c.c...../^M.1. 
0000790: 6f0a 0344 68a6 4779 198d e4ca f189 65aa  o..Dh.Gy......e.
00007a0: 2f6e 8b2f ff74 48c8 4b91 9efa bfc4 5aea  /n./.tH.K.....Z.
00007b0: 7a72 d0c5 fb50 e29a a788 86d1 d787 c9d0  zr...P..........
00007c0: d997 3e81 b830 3bde 83bc e502 cf3f 000a  ..>..0;......?..
00007d0: 7cfe 0360 ea3f 71cf 5f22 c6f0 fcc2 2786  |..`.?q._"....'.
00007e0: ac8b 533a 13b9 1370 637b 3251 104e 88ba  ..S:...pc{2Q.N..
00007f0: f8c6 6a9c 5642 66db 2a8f e29e a610 a86e  ..j.VBf.*......n
0000800: 618f fa4c 69ae 953e 7e48 89cd 9382 26fc  a..Li..>~H....&.
0000810: 5b6f 6aaf 4a15 4f4a 9d62 6768 72e3 08da  [oj.J.OJ.bghr...
0000820: 3dff 6789 a0d2 8927 d73e d17d 019c 6a70  =.g....'.>.}..jp
0000830: d2fd ff07                                ....
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZpp21U10oW/@yuC2k5o2JkTW6TRtgUcEFRQWtHs7ERAJhFl9q/73pV9HuDqD@@5Lg/Tc@pUqlattSrbdv327Xrrzu33fvnj1t9/L/vrfRVbCSoUv6mUtlW5unQ1NruqUNeinOtJuZycUjf191880O9rffyKdjr//soMYAjRemqqtVpVXV1VcStObakktfYYVbFrU6kum1L6qdb6/Vu86aH1Y72HsITwa86qhehUrsOrvASvTGubqsMMZRbi@OyrUp9p3fj4N3oGOXNuD@EkRO18jzdJhZEX1Rcb1JJDI4FGZmmrKqyBg5zT9/VPWv9D/yAx/vv1HsITwm1bVtmFohK5cC4OUuvY1LD8cQsuKOcli5Naf//00szhkg7@kEUgRF@7Ud3ZpLYtUhXTneo2WBVMpcRmFGU2J7XQ@k19k/eLF/RvWp/cQ0RCbGXd@DKSzi4VtZpAg0Zb1CiuqZFNVat0Sc3vf6S/5TAfyG/3EEk6UlJQra5JmVCyqnHl8N51lf1WlHXDKO/zSog/ZhD9zYdav6b/fQiRpRY2eZWWuKpqwqpyy06VajfVawuKc0SKJCHs/bu/6v8S4z0J9PQQokgW3g1VS@xqGW5RxdOW1dRO@taqsWavqosLWZzSt/UyE3mV/37eQ1Qpp98W0GA7WZigeisLHUmr8gPApG6NcmP1h1rI68l5/dexU4csVkKsoa1qzXxwSyEr29ehRjCcKySjVgGHCTEfQnw332mIvraHaISwsRS1lEo/F0BmItiOmWZkEzhNr4tqK@BQbxySuPaBvsovYQ@xESLlXFQZ2VIBEB03AL5swDqZaFWLvSjf5CAPZ4Bb3@jx26r154eDdEIEJz@@WkYqbIZvrCQVA8Hy4pk/cBFSAFpfjyd7Ij9d4@3yj3uIIdCqBQzUsimTe1DRJqqbPNAyGcBs9HNzLR2Vc72r/7X/7pV91glhwsYoxCzzCRqW6rNy62AyBvWJHcTWyJH2EO/pM/@U7j7S6x5C@GLb@EzZKFjemlPRGKOGa16VJQ6pSlZbn3xxRgetqwS6o68dZTH5wjOarfCTNaek8qhCGhsJNBcp8RpUiaYp9W@aoR9IhJvxxUGEL0Lkg7Sywjuer42cZl1TV6GBi57XTDltUeqSfPw8R/nrB3Bx@e09hPDFWiLjXD34itvgbWEyQgedlgalvgATx48ofV1/thfyI/2Xbtf3EMIXq4cg1hg5gy00tS@UczSw7YV5LbGd5CPl/EUCnIK97Gcf/LaHEL5IwRc6AltHy6AE2wafgcSaKZ6C1ATIOI364ywt1Rf1B99TDTC@hxC@2PICrBMFGwnGbBmYFJGD4oY7EJ9r5dDUHw4oD@4QQvjClg5hFQ4y6gK9hFSVHd5IBWD1bbHwDqBXb8@DfPL4xOkGk7/2zR5C@GJZB@rRiGNqbrBxqEJ3KwBnwtCRik4YYa1JnCevSG81ld1DCF8YC5hNRYpSWFY1PBOfbY7E9hB6zEN54TQlwP5jH/f/aP2vX/cQwhfULyorh28e1qeulMZL2E5TswUhq/dA6yIEri/9queM/KU/30MIX6Q1GFAO3YWE@G0xiCZkktoCzdiAia@QvHpyAUBpzfuzy8/0ucNBhC@sFd4uQGKJpjMjCeYIzvLBbGRQPFINgNWrsxX1nrbntN7ef7CHEL6I0fHpSkfWinqgwBS2r3BVhjYX1yHVhWIz/Du0eB17MSOTLzYSiKEy8Z1mbNZlxl7mfIOGmCMPJbuJi671FZ1hrje01@WVXdjlINUl5cuGIBbg2DKdXVYnvNOFB5GIbBk99U46u@eAENw6pd/bQ0y@SCvEFyhDK5khjVC/TXI4oQrbkNM10CqlD3L2ptHX3j2pL@0hhC@66HklA@q3YGsGdGfruqrFRgggepHLTQ6Cqp9jyN7R@ob@5FAL6yaDQ7/dAubNFjI3kCV/VZBGGQ@Ih0SZXvVwiEWBta7rEI/KaYUvQsfbOFNWhHVzoAqDMzL1W1FtgJc2FQvWQV3VRt@VkxR99@Kz62/uISZfiLdZOnLRk7ckQB/QZiogzDvW6pR3rR0m9SP9xrQI@uNDFtNfeNxdqs2CBmjTDQG4LSJuGAbGzCkbglDO8ceTcPbXPy7sIYQvjOlZzJ6lLXUVSVsgLIC5FrLAD3qJs2uqlZ7clyzuH9UiT2gNQRXyH3AUkDeUPQL48hWc5sy4ru5glH4WMdX5nMzqbpTs5AsoFMo2FiR2MUo0sBqRtEgqPuI0lhzLS@bg7pz2nX6t8AXKCcl1prI7salij2qiQZvwckniXUR2FSxzeR5DXrf12EOsE50V@TIolx/4ggnrkYo4Nd5ICj@NcZpZ3DmvX7z2EMIXELjMCA6reSaV0pDAMJI@spLE@6UGaahv9NmXAhy8lhW@aAGi7hSQnyTpLYpvyuDChVUMtEVn@/RaWn/99Pakb9j39u61bJ/KTgLWJ9pS8GerzFrDdCizYnpgcdSef5EQr/85jRrojiePDiJ8UR0HHZlUMJ@cO2KGV0H5Ghi9YVNWS2jxpY7I6@EhhBO@WGkoFgVfFQscvCWDFlbgWCOwhk0g53GwKFev8/YY9nwnnjiEEL5AKFaSBtspw1DWY/HoVZKpY8vAheGlhLWOy5f713dg6K931nLCF3HBEmwrDt4xJFAgFgWNXJRbsH1V@GLuFurn8/qmEfLTywfwxQ97COGLKvsIRtdgluEYRh/hYEegQfi8zUOGUP2u7Mcgmy/1V09f4MIJX@TW5AzsDKGSRe1oanQ4WWwBGl/iJuibTX0I@@rHTb@uy62jEMIXS4NyNiwzRwJB2WDe0SRWiC7ltJR4pHZYJn4W/3ww4XsI4QvrDFlYcGHYaUA5WEqbOJZGdVlF@Du@QanX9L0/cUqvPfsFCdBfHEIIX0BaCLgBQWnB1tRGOVnVZNtjX6tAFk2Ysoys39XPB22XZTf9BQKqeoS3u19xzA2q3VbBpGwCLdERb7zgIh9gBTL1J6c/3UPs@4hFbDws60X3isendMl8HfwD29JATKpkcUI/OxjfE1q/eziI8EUaOKPh@czorFhbHY3Oglh2XuosEM3r2A4A39XIv2jq9BdV2rYCiSWg4tsingT@FYQIBUI@i3CaunILVGxan35bhOgoxOQLGQ8j4LDiAbrYhCT2Ow/OlZKAvmeaegXifOfBfpIH/iiE8EURi9ci6LSO9D2cg66Jh5ThYe@UxX3bJ/XYazSTZuj0PAvhC99xQcFmFm42SrUZ2dKILtXF9ASSckms65efX9QXRUZOSlHTbl2d8IVJg097RtMHDP9WIEuXk4BM/CvH4e/MzOKbWYT85/nvn9fCC19UL@McUF9Tkc4cYWPKiZXGH6klGQjdb5O1vpWVW58@9hL9euGLEVlwV7m1SK7DeeyJ4J0K@NbkhEyLFd1Xsub@TlvvsZdd1K@2PYSd6GTx8hb6xaaE/fogjSF6RH1ir0P1hTelf/zo6wt6vzu4/TyL6S8KNj62MRd3UO4cyhSY7hSZvw6zAXVQox6dFfer/6n1n/LrjT3E9BcJGx8CK81ITMsmWxGOZahQghXjwR@ls@qy1ELm5M73F83zLMLcijhy6pi01FDSlizUFT0@ZeC85x7vAuqqLmF5n97FJwk0lnAIMfcRtig2F747um4BAkZzjE1mH8@GuCZlhYbUE23nZQ70ax7BgXsI4QtXAxWIUNciC9qCD4V8YAmX8E258Ed2VUK8/@2RiKSXmjr9xWopmHNy84J1XVYQUiNcVcQm2HUsKFyTSVXaXriyBzn@PITwRXf40rGIL4ibYBsH76wRymHWRhH/ZTfBxXt7L@zuuQ4hhC8CcseSSRn8EAmRvaaKxWNpFFWE0EdFE9RXP8iOOS@F5Gbsqz3EOn0nBVslgZDF9sWCdfXwRZbtEwYaqshp5s2B7DOvv62vv6iF8EVrlhkpCefNBsJ8AjLjMGnVgNNhRVvytGtvff907jP39aUXIYQv1gbAS@kQNTSGIAIJJ2tQqLKobCJpGAgBuGCzf@E/nzX9bg8hfJEDS0AU6i@NPuRNNjuRoi6FXTcMQ8nVH613QjgvT6rwxdiYadYgzF5GLpwcCQIAWqKzaVCpKpczalrnXwuHufdipQlzH1mbKFeWONZDGoAMQaamyQMt4eCAKOzmQIs3@OTNj/UnVw8hhC9MYYaymINusKmbhXJQUuQJ9qEq6GwdbswsborhRE9vwL6n9hDCF0ZwkV0tsDX8NRBDZIUdr3oK2y3F3poRdIILCPy0vseg/Xh0EOEL5@DJtRW5xIAs86CBq4cxvaHH@L@OmhFbOYHmZM3T@taRmgXhC1wra20ZAHPjSC7MiAY9cmJW0FjCLtRiOgMdCPTxly/KGeblAz45RkJUMfTRyc2ezCd8hUVhdZPFiab@IVe@ulEKo08@ebjtIYQvghB@g6TJQsyykysZMlCxCm0GcNpXOch3f06yQVFv6OfLREjzjg@Ar4aNP0UKTycdRhIBGmITQBpjH@eG@BaTeuq@OyBr3xCD8MWoKFcWDXNNpFGUoFoOPwxuvFu5uA1doHXycN36MjrD9BebrPiWLPyGt1mDbDiJiE3uO3tHqlO0cyu6dzgJ0Hjw51t7COELL@X2pohvH7K905YegKiJXmoqN8MNgVHnaWbYQ5x9zuBh8kVpHBlpp7Nyqx9kcZfO7sRXo/Ag7lY9ktugL/64ItT1TtPn9xDCF5tFENlQWQmFeT3eQtlNJmwV@yii7XJepiBSik/1e8eegNJ8yGLnC9b@asXG@yb8D3UZA98uiX8ohsE92LWkr25HFP70YNeC8EWpILEauJMtCGdkQHTpRq5FmrQX9hstLP@zTFw/cGcY08Y3OGaBoUpl4GoQf9FgzC73ILlQ7DIWzMHPgvAfXjT2lf0yXkTAGuEqNv5isEfdsV31LFcgkBXGlrCrN9vzLG5LChJqDyF84RaYzhiqBiwAwoA5tiwbNMWAgQBrCHL5MK/A7WS/37X79hBi3nfKgwOfcVOsx2I5EY4ehHQrm0AzovZFpOi0PvPbOVGQuTEfZTH5ojBXlf1OhdY9bIN9jBlEh6XjNFiVWN@oiip0VK74rumvXqrF3EfEsg/PaZIn/Q4mVExYC4utR6PE@Rw2xN3C/3JR5OzZIUSYjo8dcKt4re5YfiB9cRUsh028/ACe@MEhuHj4vKUnxf3tIeJ80CMePKxi7LAWYaUga/KslpscLoMV9tlVHvTMBzxan9Gffvf8IHMfSYtYIYuDXwjRPeazDFoQKx9cIpzmbN/d7z/2JG7M1uwh8tzZ@UwVNHiHT@59WFnLxPYFASs4bQNxY2fXtz/epeTbF@UUvnCRaUK9ZA@Dxqv4xRIZcfYs9ubMUmJYP5WKWINXj6px4iiE8EVcDV8mC5EtkGXYGPtCHTgDImk5kyqyMCrR0rf1j6sI49vPsxC@qHJrvVR4qcsiWHyTNRFgwhkYhk1sgvU7wN@aGfx@@Sbd/WIPMZ@PrJCTD@wRBUbHvfmVPriJEKrLYg/yBRfHz2Lif37/s@/yfs@3hxC@cAIjJmPbjbhFDFECGNN5VtSlUQYjO5NKFxExfeLTuc8cud8ofLE1qD82aGosILGJg4@lywMaufLbrDz6kOcj@tTNYztVTGztz0ei8IVtWLMud60V2y9PRdgJbDfyfBK2SXJ5Ks9G1btvQuHvCo/Pe/3jr@xP3qZdQzV3w59wamPZFsqAF3UJG8@SaWFo18Wu3d4bqrCu9x59uIcwUxD5ipiYz6XKaLYhN0HAsSQ@HQ3CEDrAU98dP7q31feqvnp7DyF8sRlcThswC5sLwYoRT8LohU1umSKsNXzeJ9W9@iuVePjjC9ZK83nqvDGXT9dN7NGgGesCf@33@7KWuSGXlZ/9B6f2yYkHYn/P6lP7ZWUSvtjEBRk@rpIsymgJCQgQYrHyKKvIYwXr5wPASVkX9PU3nmj3@h5i8kXHQayy3lUnMhiyfC0EAdvRJdmbt8la8@Jiv660IP1wkDivQCKezuBoTMxyPSpjJk9Wlz2BqS1T2fuFL@WqVC5M3dGMpOkv5AqkLfJApOIGjEMQe6ICq4gbNhQlKHNDfOlVHut9Q0xzH4lxPrFyss3w43JTVjZGPHRxPoHVqDYrB2mHpejE1S/wSmoPIXwRxRwsuG55IMJ2mjiDkVu6LjdcgLXIXT0zckfrf1/Tnz7a8@iHgwhf2AFu8srXUkOPouAVvBil0ofcg4C5edWkTtyGaO6fOTy2unIIMf1FBYTbAkuMNQi2RVZSxnNEIfSEs24F0KvH9/jkV/9jlNL0FwW6c13ui7MslCsskeX@tQfEuAlq5PmvlPNDeOKfzzu7h5jPU@dQyNPjXsXxmUYlh5VHqexCg40HUQIr6qlca536Tf/06r5d7SGEL6o8vg7OVfqJmLAQMbgOuDkbDA4dwOS8ziy@fl@W1PbEXtBfHmUx9xF8FppRWIMi22CMIMTWPKQqLIyoP4tVnLdrN/Slj4Y8Vpgm4ZX9Mbs01fDjLOpiKCr0G@CG1FGzLNtpcQwpG3xTqmr9OXP64V9nJMIbexZ58sXKij/NsmehQ1E8tkaUIKaYhb@cXCRzkP/euaHP6fPn9PrLtXtHHcl2/p8PmKKYQFBdEPUsK@qWSGUzCc9mOGGs1Eed3B8VvUljnnGou3sIN02j/I8SY2GQ/v@XfP7vvy/fubP9fp3Gf1Xv/fp/)

I have no doubt this can be golfed *much* more, the problem is Cinnamon Gum's lack of complete docs. (@quartata pls this has great chance of being amazing troll lang) I might dig into the source code to see if there's anything that can be beneficial to this.

[This](https://tio.run/##nVvPU9w6Er7zV6h8yEA9SG3e7l6ylUMgCbw8SFjgZQ6pHDS2wNqRJa9kM5n957MteQBb6rYNOaQS8klu9c@vW0q9bUqjf//1y7F3LMuyvex93hjNbsxGZyz@9ZZ9zz5I11iZN9lhdinznBdSqW32Axaq4o43Il21W3giba4ELLsQjTW1UbLhureQfeSuyca/eMarSlhXyaZkr9iJbHZfroUFqTPiy5GcfoeSVxQ6EU/fCYWeqsN/MbYphe2wNi83fJvNw2rj2Kk196nOEKmtE5orcuch@pivhWXXjRUCVWn4d2UMqPTRLIhuD7PP7UoqgVntmCtCielRj7leExrsXEPoxsLhDp9WHWZL8AkvY8/Qx9yuZM5JQ4@fJT2BXUt9R6p00u92GzhZ4BZ8OFYHNdqxE9PaKR@PLbl1G6@JbOLIjzv4RSI32hs/mzhZwCon/yfYJRwmm7KjsJXRhRNbPDc8eEuANiX4K/i3ELG9Yt0onq9vreTWZfOP6BeVBqKCXRleZPGib4AzsGfAgsxEMETu1z@Asaa9K2eF8rFxPmlecG1sNh2cpgUdoppB0Zv0hM/yUgvHYyfWOFy9g4NY@ZNIpKlWramU2B6ttkcgY/YCwVqwYGtdw87gsNmoi7QWzvCVr7NpY5xwJQqjJde4ZwzVe8KrQhD1Lt1Z84KzJRaOkft7qN2yZcnt7TRUQxZBRUCg4GeoK5ORAot86sHiO9m/5OoWMgcY6Zw3suofEyuNHr9mn7itsmmzlFznAnRyzrUYTwgAtV4jmM9G1Wv4BUHVdUJ6ebcRSmUTVamDuo3M15gW44R6AlkJ4mJjTJHNEkPxGsSG2lBVceglStxhw88yNgt7bdpprIEMDElMECk4ihkQXhcQZnOi0SglYVu2TPWRYu99qjrltkBrRiSFNT@V2M429wd@J7RXCMIzYxs@Ys8EbyJGl2DFKhUXd6MPXhkOSXdpKH7kyocAJFlexIxyWLP6suxWYa40TjM@cqsWL@EnXpks9AzZ1OkD9JPUeZmaLXaFgD2jSfpkcQkbXLaNRjwktqDH5gZvXRJPShRQ3G24FbN4wg6L1nOKlk@fVAmI85C0T@Agg6gcyZYfVYXXBExB1QoYfAWmxI08Iffgs3VNce7EX1pHcZGhZg8HvKRbxq7/26ZmeX6T8IlLOFmdzZAX6qAvWwUZCs/78C5Q2MMXRvzqEYs4Vj@voF9xqxaqMlHYer4@1PKn1rd/dH7qu88peCeR9WIdnirT5sIXIpy8Ye41jMdTowpfb6jGo683jy35Zk3pbcxiYbkp7gRNxwafslwDlkz9fR1YKDrsEhYrHjcuz/ejoIdbY4ts0oEDlEgKQzci3eK01RpE8i41mXbPuNS8Vc0M/tU76cwWkdDO0FcAUoOv8WIGkTnz9rMYe0WkBQLocFIwSJcd1kKH94otBVeFz1xP2@PYI6OPQKqjoSthjOeMNz4Toq1fyqcC1fGy3ECXD5ZRjr05ZL8fsr9nc9DsH9kz9mb/HEXrwsudJj7ELPKuZMfcaqK3j7Eh2b1ifzhPlHrlJe5uPZYaZ6IydGHK/hTa9Xcm2zJvvrFqMUo6zoxaGasnqxKyLuQUatjTd2KAGsjsVG6MN7ZQglqbl9kkmzgzrXawN1XZ4p13aIK2E@ilmIPeFt3gC4gveJAdl@SPfB2aghfRRPALPfQ42p@8DxGjsyQnPPkb2/@qtlUt@UFGKB6wjXQlOWmIZBglX0MZNrumzU0m/T@lghCkPbfXAu2gpLMORPBzWLTqINvqO9/q@KwIUfsa9te55UH0Z5bXwbyarIl/asgPjVtZCWxh0ifPebGyZi2wm4EZnOScVysBP6EmBH2lQS3LeeBap0mmi7LBbhxEdi5TUgm5Y3UpLY@ofKQNsR11w76IATqsoBRU3gtbG6MQ7jZMn8/jWucmFK5jytJPBKofaud@zjxyfdUT/ILLgrNv6Ogltm6YRjNIiG7O/RKgnQTZMTxZwy64XSnB3mNpP5HcbpVYYcZJJQclsY@6yCar22RzDFupQLqR8hGnvAujW7zHHVOBMXaMJ7wsm@w2php0jOxdGDs6hhrubXfFCNKgcHn/0DH2i@CO2jjKrF/EhuolY3cIXyDmRii0m2xNs9gOHUrnRkZuGYsboB2pzmZouMMvRbXC51d9Fw7YWymA0s8IvoA2szqhACVG0aTQ6Cx6Ah@ixmXT@KbxI8cQY1EZIVJpP3y@8jUhHKanr4q8x0v89qsvN8R8GNn5nquxG@rBzj99O838edqJ64mn0/cJwSUvijEu@KIxYKCxV2bLiSHL8LyAdv5WiJqS9G10Kay8x6f9sXc@fSRVT3SySB5ZKZmbWRePl1Jr9D6ccNFLxeE0aYzPniVfQo70uZIiP8kHw9iZpgF95f67BQMs3CySG7AEy41yWwfFn6JENrvi9wDN/eQ/kSKW9opv/XgHnYJMtkBXokA5MCaTuIO/4GqJtXIFad6/SpgzyAbsugKmsyHYcWzJK@MD1RMuPOX3RfahN3JFPcGQr1rplKzn3WYlmu0Wo01YLOYOir1VmPEd5wTkeWy2nuYY31t95pVwiB1JPhUWmdKHRHJjGPl417u1auEmx8rXAnycXUvshjNOL9elqCHVFyDBcevKMWVGUFCqXT/Uphk2v1YG4mjGTcVAQRrA0Ewas55iTuHmdzZz6tA0HcLQ8bTrOYP6xx2QOhjHeIfFYwQ99FJ6lhYP1@JKvsOCn6UDcmzbEUI3MJHHEk0BockNTfQHHs@rwD2OU/MnQkAAV8aSVXuwrah9wZokA6QjNyZfE08pRm7qrn2v3pUENEEMPAAM0cy4xhi84bpui9CQYLcuiCF2aGo8FqE30vkL86bho70@QG9EVeP0aSTOb0qxDcMEI91EM3VjTODgxyKfnIE/YpGLuxTbNN0ziPAuYMB/iGebg1VnCWmMc23Adg7wii1L0fTGN6k0G2HHbhFRLba32lesOa8bb1obxJ4RBkNX8AtruRbU06Yh@q@6ktrRLzr74j9iETKZYjXxGgbDej5L3/RNRvxfP0kqN00jvvH2Z8nph1d9D3n88@zYGeaYJVcNGNXz/@S@If7WkmvqNjAOuSWUSaFnXP3G0tjQu78HOtIisdHPeA/vn7OpCfwhNldE308vyRSK09/drAO9iUvE3WGpSKPfIPirmplPiALUPzytGzPVtgbszOdGAfvi50aDmvOwFXaxHNWFHRQjXIQ5XENQLvz0RFOBKHUFCV4jj8BnsFi/nMpoVIT2lVDKRnSbTVrfQ/OS10JlL8paS8hA4WIeyfGxbR6hn1udN7Kv7sT1UbJJ2OUBS8zvBlg/hkNvAbG6EtDo84R5ZkRZMG4HgPr/9EB15/3IyrLvb94evfnx2tXgx9CJCLd/sLdn2Tu2WOztwReZZFIz93bPL7fst3dMduD9xdvFwfe//XhtvUrq/YNuJ/YbW7xa@N8PF6//Y6TeF/dc7Q8WvflxcPDailrxXOwD@pAtuC4WB37Vv@CztZW6YfbXr/8D) is the Python script I hacked together to generate the compressed string.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/),  <s>1430</s>   <s>1418</s>  1416 bytes

```python
n=i=0
for e in(input()+' '*26)[:26]:n=n*256+ord(e)
w=bin(n)[2:]
for j in'Bakerloo,Central,Circle,District,Hammersmith & City,Jubilee,Metropolitan,Northern,Piccadilly,Victoria,Waterloo & City'.split(','):
 for z,o in eval('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'.decode('base64').decode('zip'))[i]:
	if all([w[k]<'1'for k in z]+[w[k]>'0'for k in o]):print j
 i+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZRJk6pYFITXXb/CVVs@jFZABSq6OgKRURAZRKGiFgwXvMjsZfzz1fVed3RvM86XmXEWWY3oXhbE11fxDt/XL3HZzMAMFq@wqFr0usDms/kPYrf4eCN2n2/Fe/GD2O6wsoleweKlfw@@L4vFB/H2@YtMv8n53n@AJivLJQcK1PjZkoNNmIHlAT5RA0O0lPw8B80zh@g@@33GQTQulTaAGQBLDaCmrMoMIr9YnsoG3UFTLM8wDP0IZtm4dL4Nygb6y6uPfqX86zD/41l9U6/z5Xzx9jL7WWZalt91ZqDzs9c5UIaTE2YDO/Gav0nOUmQ6kI4ZNPBspRu0dj81yDLYBKXn7UqvyLheh9ee1OmoDpwVZauxE@h0t@pWF68mvWsTRPaTV6gHdjbJ1AsuGwq/Vh6QuqRVvbFgPBQ4VUD1VNwQ27S8CKGOfB0E@kB795ukgZQgE7TeEyuFXlHOJqq749Dlk2PYuzYShslN210SBCJebrHvALkaqsDplNOoGqComaTFTLdlZBnW3LNVTzqFBYETGc4zZMWTXUeXh@jxnhXdNF7ImPByXq15D7@4B450ObthSktWxsd0TXY3WF7qMBfHIyFakyugvQgRW6na7TD4R6rfUBIe@eOa4yw7EW0ZCFSP@qctbbt1Qbo3KdjweZPn0lPnwco8btFNKEqTHlpLQiepuPhVYfV3bXdtEHMYrF0Qj5l8vNmP@8Ru6mbdnfWrNurDJH3/VBJijSXFwN0X2GnQY9ber1TT8yxsYITQzTzjuN04Vv3suWx7d4e0kvXNnoQ6YeMnsFYqnL7y14Mz5o@nLkKy4cWNnW4b2tHwVJJGfjJ0TZPSQqgNLtfXMjXS3iVxyV5ZDceOEsQjR/CqUrR5ad1i/KQO/tN6no8quInmARhDquphlSVKYHdrWdcfdb2dilLoYOiYmkgnTcmqeYy0/qwQRagFIGRVUrxaKwyK3EUsBHdN3CXsPhTXNcuHmfxUeTSptqnCli6Z284WurbDixtQThFKwyyVNWBoBwccDyV@hBq7Z2qHp0vbX5NN1iRRpihZwuZ1dXBuFYsiCC4HVh2OveWrU57jQdxTyYEZjcYNZJNND9Y1m6jinAE4erpt189YnvCULXY2g7sjPxDqA/IZe3aavupF2D7uBlPjOnajTVyHKkfZVoYeY2vwKnRRSSVo4w7ntYh50ARZwUNrg3GOruirnaAnJ5nou1NGW@2Z4FzeiS4gPdxb0zzSxVmxLceJb7lElFYswY0HReaK7ajUlZXBv/i6G5GsbY@m2eo3ORV9oTgPoRTp6t0QuHtphMi1@GgfnzuhCQsfmlty29XNTskORY7o5LBdMQ9E4ldvQ8m7nml43CbjB@6Ffput8ai2gtVJFlT55MCYMrawWQV@G4Ze23MdQ8bUQK8khoLzPyIQlhF4nQf@E@w288V/wgSr@WLxAT/fXn6D8czPsteP/uPx@eccn//cosfPJZo@sV/iX/P1/2L5uXirGligWfoyg9g7/vX1z4LOLNQAgOZ/Aw)

**Explanation**
The input is encoded as a binary representation (8-bits ASCII code for each letter of the input word) when completing the input word by spaces at right if the length of the word is less than 26. I already done the same representation for all possible inputs and find the minimal bits that differentiate the outputs. The code looks at these specific bits to decide on the output.

- -12 bytes thanks to Jonathan Allan.
- -2 bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder when using lexicographical comparison.

Comment: This is pretty cool. Can you use unprintable characters and have the base64-decoded string instead? A single byte may be saved with `s=(s+' '*22)[:26]` instead of `s+=' '*(26-len(s))`.

Comment: ...and another nine by inlining that and input fetch: `n=0` newline `for e in(input()+' '*26)[:26]:n=n*256+ord(e)`. Two more by using `n=i=0` at the top too.

Comment: @JonathanAllan thanx a lot for your remarks. Please fell free to edit the answer :)

Comment: Edited in the 12 bytes saved. I'm unsure about the unprintable characters (I get `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character...` when I try to do it) - might need an encoding header or something.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Non-ASCII characters in Python 2 require UTF-8 to be declared at the top of the program with `#coding:utf-8`.

Comment: @LyricLy yeah that's what I was trying.

Comment: ...note that I gave up because even with the errors the byte count seemed greater.

Comment: [1416 (-2 bytes)](https://goo.gl/WJzVRH), using lexicographical comparison.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jotlin 1.0](https://github.com/jrtapsell/jotlin), 1539 bytes

### Submission

```kotlin
{x->d("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").split("~").w{v ->Regex("(-?[0-9]+)([A-Z]+)").findAll(v[1]).f{x.hashCode()%2897==b.groupValues[1].toInt()}.m{b.groupValues[2].m{v[0].split("|")[b-'A']}}.first()}}
```

### Test code

```kotlin
var v:(String)->List<String> =
{x->d("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").split("~").w{v ->Regex("(-?[0-9]+)([A-Z]+)").findAll(v[1]).f{x.hashCode()%2897==b.groupValues[1].toInt()}.m{b.groupValues[2].m{v[0].split("|")[b-'A']}}.first()}}
data class Test(val input0: String, val output: List<String>)

val tests = listOf<Test>(
    Test("""Acton Town""",listOf("""District""","""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Aldgate""",listOf("""Circle""","""Metropolitan""")),
    Test("""Aldgate East""",listOf("""District""","""Hammersmith & City""")),
    Test("""Alperton""",listOf("""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Amersham""",listOf("""Metropolitan""")),
    Test("""Angel""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""Archway""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""Arnos Grove""",listOf("""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Arsenal""",listOf("""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Baker Street""",listOf("""Bakerloo""","""Circle""","""Hammersmith & City""","""Jubilee""","""Metropolitan""")),
    Test("""Balham""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""Bank""",listOf("""Central""","""Northern""","""Waterloo & City""")),
    Test("""Barbican""",listOf("""Circle""","""Hammersmith & City""","""Metropolitan""")),
    Test("""Barking""",listOf("""District""","""Hammersmith & City""")),
    Test("""Barkingside""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Barons Court""",listOf("""District""","""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Bayswater""",listOf("""Circle""","""District""")),
    Test("""Becontree""",listOf("""District""")),
    Test("""Belsize Park""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""Bermondsey""",listOf("""Jubilee""")),
    Test("""Bethnal Green""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Blackfriars""",listOf("""Circle""","""District""")),
    Test("""Blackhorse Road""",listOf("""Victoria""")),
    Test("""Bond Street""",listOf("""Central""","""Jubilee""")),
    Test("""Borough""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""Boston Manor""",listOf("""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Bounds Green""",listOf("""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Bow Road""",listOf("""District""","""Hammersmith & City""")),
    Test("""Brent Cross""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""Brixton""",listOf("""Victoria""")),
    Test("""Bromley-by-Bow""",listOf("""District""","""Hammersmith & City""")),
    Test("""Buckhurst Hill""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Burnt Oak""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""Caledonian Road""",listOf("""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Camden Town""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""Canada Water""",listOf("""Jubilee""")),
    Test("""Canary Wharf""",listOf("""Jubilee""")),
    Test("""Canning Town""",listOf("""Jubilee""")),
    Test("""Cannon Street""",listOf("""Circle""","""District""")),
    Test("""Canons Park""",listOf("""Jubilee""")),
    Test("""Chalfont & Latimer""",listOf("""Metropolitan""")),
    Test("""Chalk Farm""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""Chancery Lane""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Charing Cross""",listOf("""Bakerloo""","""Northern""")),
    Test("""Chesham""",listOf("""Metropolitan""")),
    Test("""Chigwell""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Chiswick Park""",listOf("""District""")),
    Test("""Chorleywood""",listOf("""Metropolitan""")),
    Test("""Clapham Common""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""Clapham North""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""Clapham South""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""Cockfosters""",listOf("""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Colindale""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""Colliers Wood""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""Covent Garden""",listOf("""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Croxley""",listOf("""Metropolitan""")),
    Test("""Dagenham East""",listOf("""District""")),
    Test("""Dagenham Heathway""",listOf("""District""")),
    Test("""Debden""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Dollis Hill""",listOf("""Jubilee""")),
    Test("""Ealing Broadway""",listOf("""Central""","""District""")),
    Test("""Ealing Common""",listOf("""District""","""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Earl's Court""",listOf("""District""","""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""East Acton""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""East Finchley""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""East Ham""",listOf("""District""","""Hammersmith & City""")),
    Test("""East Putney""",listOf("""District""")),
    Test("""Eastcote""",listOf("""Metropolitan""","""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Edgware""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""Edgware Road""",listOf("""Bakerloo""","""Circle""","""District""","""Hammersmith & City""")),
    Test("""Elephant & Castle""",listOf("""Bakerloo""","""Northern""")),
    Test("""Elm Park""",listOf("""District""")),
    Test("""Embankment""",listOf("""Bakerloo""","""Circle""","""District""","""Northern""")),
    Test("""Epping""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Euston""",listOf("""Northern""","""Victoria""")),
    Test("""Euston Square""",listOf("""Circle""","""Hammersmith & City""","""Metropolitan""")),
    Test("""Fairlop""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Farringdon""",listOf("""Circle""","""Hammersmith & City""","""Metropolitan""")),
    Test("""Finchley Central""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""Finchley Road""",listOf("""Jubilee""","""Metropolitan""")),
    Test("""Finsbury Park""",listOf("""Piccadilly""","""Victoria""")),
    Test("""Fulham Broadway""",listOf("""District""")),
    Test("""Gants Hill""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Gloucester Road""",listOf("""Circle""","""District""","""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Golders Green""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""Goldhawk Road""",listOf("""Circle""","""Hammersmith & City""")),
    Test("""Goodge Street""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""Grange Hill""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Great Portland Street""",listOf("""Circle""","""Hammersmith & City""","""Metropolitan""")),
    Test("""Greenford""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Green Park""",listOf("""Jubilee""","""Piccadilly""","""Victoria""")),
    Test("""Gunnersbury""",listOf("""District""")),
    Test("""Hainault""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Hammersmith""",listOf("""Circle""","""District""","""Hammersmith & City""","""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Hampstead""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""Hanger Lane""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Harlesden""",listOf("""Bakerloo""")),
    Test("""Harrow & Wealdstone""",listOf("""Bakerloo""")),
    Test("""Harrow-on-the-Hill""",listOf("""Metropolitan""")),
    Test("""Hatton Cross""",listOf("""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Heathrow Terminals 1, 2, 3""",listOf("""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Heathrow Terminal 4""",listOf("""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Heathrow Terminal 5""",listOf("""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Hendon Central""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""High Barnet""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""Highbury & Islington""",listOf("""Victoria""")),
    Test("""Highgate""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""High Street Kensington""",listOf("""Circle""","""District""")),
    Test("""Hillingdon""",listOf("""Metropolitan""","""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Holborn""",listOf("""Central""","""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Holland Park""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Holloway Road""",listOf("""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Hornchurch""",listOf("""District""")),
    Test("""Hounslow Central""",listOf("""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Hounslow East""",listOf("""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Hounslow West""",listOf("""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Hyde Park Corner""",listOf("""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Ickenham""",listOf("""Metropolitan""","""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Kennington""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""Kensal Green""",listOf("""Bakerloo""")),
    Test("""Kensington (Olympia)""",listOf("""District""")),
    Test("""Kentish Town""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""Kenton""",listOf("""Bakerloo""")),
    Test("""Kew Gardens""",listOf("""District""")),
    Test("""Kilburn""",listOf("""Jubilee""")),
    Test("""Kilburn Park""",listOf("""Bakerloo""")),
    Test("""Kingsbury""",listOf("""Jubilee""")),
    Test("""King's Cross St. Pancras""",listOf("""Circle""","""Hammersmith & City""","""Metropolitan""","""Northern""","""Piccadilly""","""Victoria""")),
    Test("""Knightsbridge""",listOf("""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Ladbroke Grove""",listOf("""Circle""","""Hammersmith & City""")),
    Test("""Lambeth North""",listOf("""Bakerloo""")),
    Test("""Lancaster Gate""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Latimer Road""",listOf("""Circle""","""Hammersmith & City""")),
    Test("""Leicester Square""",listOf("""Northern""","""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Leyton""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Leytonstone""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Liverpool Street""",listOf("""Central""","""Circle""","""Hammersmith & City""","""Metropolitan""")),
    Test("""London Bridge""",listOf("""Jubilee""","""Northern""")),
    Test("""Loughton""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Maida Vale""",listOf("""Bakerloo""")),
    Test("""Manor House""",listOf("""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Mansion House""",listOf("""Circle""","""District""")),
    Test("""Marble Arch""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Marylebone""",listOf("""Bakerloo""")),
    Test("""Mile End""",listOf("""Central""","""District""","""Hammersmith & City""")),
    Test("""Mill Hill East""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""Monument""",listOf("""Circle""","""District""")),
    Test("""Moorgate""",listOf("""Circle""","""Hammersmith & City""","""Metropolitan""","""Northern""")),
    Test("""Moor Park""",listOf("""Metropolitan""")),
    Test("""Morden""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""Mornington Crescent""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""Neasden""",listOf("""Jubilee""")),
    Test("""Newbury Park""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""North Acton""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""North Ealing""",listOf("""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""North Greenwich""",listOf("""Jubilee""")),
    Test("""North Harrow""",listOf("""Metropolitan""")),
    Test("""North Wembley""",listOf("""Bakerloo""")),
    Test("""Northfields""",listOf("""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Northolt""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Northwick Park""",listOf("""Metropolitan""")),
    Test("""Northwood""",listOf("""Metropolitan""")),
    Test("""Northwood Hills""",listOf("""Metropolitan""")),
    Test("""Notting Hill Gate""",listOf("""Central""","""Circle""","""District""")),
    Test("""Oakwood""",listOf("""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Old Street""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""Osterley""",listOf("""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Oval""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""Oxford Circus""",listOf("""Bakerloo""","""Central""","""Victoria""")),
    Test("""Paddington""",listOf("""Bakerloo""","""Circle""","""District""","""Hammersmith & City""")),
    Test("""Park Royal""",listOf("""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Parsons Green""",listOf("""District""")),
    Test("""Perivale""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Piccadilly Circus""",listOf("""Bakerloo""","""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Pimlico""",listOf("""Victoria""")),
    Test("""Pinner""",listOf("""Metropolitan""")),
    Test("""Plaistow""",listOf("""District""","""Hammersmith & City""")),
    Test("""Preston Road""",listOf("""Metropolitan""")),
    Test("""Putney Bridge""",listOf("""District""")),
    Test("""Queen's Park""",listOf("""Bakerloo""")),
    Test("""Queensbury""",listOf("""Jubilee""")),
    Test("""Queensway""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Ravenscourt Park""",listOf("""District""")),
    Test("""Rayners Lane""",listOf("""Metropolitan""","""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Redbridge""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Regent's Park""",listOf("""Bakerloo""")),
    Test("""Richmond""",listOf("""District""")),
    Test("""Rickmansworth""",listOf("""Metropolitan""")),
    Test("""Roding Valley""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Royal Oak""",listOf("""Circle""","""Hammersmith & City""")),
    Test("""Ruislip""",listOf("""Metropolitan""","""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Ruislip Gardens""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Ruislip Manor""",listOf("""Metropolitan""","""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Russell Square""",listOf("""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""St. James's Park""",listOf("""Circle""","""District""")),
    Test("""St. John's Wood""",listOf("""Jubilee""")),
    Test("""St. Paul's""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Seven Sisters""",listOf("""Victoria""")),
    Test("""Shepherd's Bush""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Shepherd's Bush Market""",listOf("""Circle""","""Hammersmith & City""")),
    Test("""Sloane Square""",listOf("""Circle""","""District""")),
    Test("""Snaresbrook""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""South Ealing""",listOf("""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""South Harrow""",listOf("""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""South Kensington""",listOf("""Circle""","""District""","""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""South Kenton""",listOf("""Bakerloo""")),
    Test("""South Ruislip""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""South Wimbledon""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""South Woodford""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Southfields""",listOf("""District""")),
    Test("""Southgate""",listOf("""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Southwark""",listOf("""Jubilee""")),
    Test("""Stamford Brook""",listOf("""District""")),
    Test("""Stanmore""",listOf("""Jubilee""")),
    Test("""Stepney Green""",listOf("""District""","""Hammersmith & City""")),
    Test("""Stockwell""",listOf("""Northern""","""Victoria""")),
    Test("""Stonebridge Park""",listOf("""Bakerloo""")),
    Test("""Stratford""",listOf("""Central""","""Jubilee""")),
    Test("""Sudbury Hill""",listOf("""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Sudbury Town""",listOf("""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Swiss Cottage""",listOf("""Jubilee""")),
    Test("""Temple""",listOf("""Circle""","""District""")),
    Test("""Theydon Bois""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Tooting Bec""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""Tooting Broadway""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""Tottenham Court Road""",listOf("""Central""","""Northern""")),
    Test("""Tottenham Hale""",listOf("""Victoria""")),
    Test("""Totteridge & Whetstone""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""Tower Hill""",listOf("""Circle""","""District""")),
    Test("""Tufnell Park""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""Turnham Green""",listOf("""District""","""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Turnpike Lane""",listOf("""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Upminster""",listOf("""District""")),
    Test("""Upminster Bridge""",listOf("""District""")),
    Test("""Upney""",listOf("""District""")),
    Test("""Upton Park""",listOf("""District""","""Hammersmith & City""")),
    Test("""Uxbridge""",listOf("""Metropolitan""","""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Vauxhall""",listOf("""Victoria""")),
    Test("""Victoria""",listOf("""Circle""","""District""","""Victoria""")),
    Test("""Walthamstow Central""",listOf("""Victoria""")),
    Test("""Wanstead""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Warren Street""",listOf("""Northern""","""Victoria""")),
    Test("""Warwick Avenue""",listOf("""Bakerloo""")),
    Test("""Waterloo""",listOf("""Bakerloo""","""Jubilee""","""Northern""","""Waterloo & City""")),
    Test("""Watford""",listOf("""Metropolitan""")),
    Test("""Wembley Central""",listOf("""Bakerloo""")),
    Test("""Wembley Park""",listOf("""Jubilee""","""Metropolitan""")),
    Test("""West Acton""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""West Brompton""",listOf("""District""")),
    Test("""West Finchley""",listOf("""Northern""")),
    Test("""West Ham""",listOf("""District""","""Hammersmith & City""","""Jubilee""")),
    Test("""West Hampstead""",listOf("""Jubilee""")),
    Test("""West Harrow""",listOf("""Metropolitan""")),
    Test("""West Kensington""",listOf("""District""")),
    Test("""West Ruislip""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Westbourne Park""",listOf("""Circle""","""Hammersmith & City""")),
    Test("""Westminster""",listOf("""Circle""","""District""","""Jubilee""")),
    Test("""White City""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Whitechapel""",listOf("""District""","""Hammersmith & City""")),
    Test("""Willesden Green""",listOf("""Jubilee""")),
    Test("""Willesden Junction""",listOf("""Bakerloo""")),
    Test("""Wimbledon""",listOf("""District""")),
    Test("""Wimbledon Park""",listOf("""District""")),
    Test("""Wood Green""",listOf("""Piccadilly""")),
    Test("""Wood Lane""",listOf("""Circle""","""Hammersmith & City""")),
    Test("""Woodford""",listOf("""Central""")),
    Test("""Woodside Park""",listOf("""Northern"""))
)

for (r in tests) {
    val result = v(r.input0)
    if (result != r.output) {
        error("Error during $r, expected ${r.output}, got $result")
    } else {
        print(jotlin.runner.TestUtils.tick)
    }
}
```

Comment: Port of my Kotlin answer to Jotlin